# How to build a decorator with optional parameters?

Tags: python, decorator

I would like to make a decorator which could be used with or without a parameter :
Something like this :

```
class d(object):
    def __init__(self,msg='my default message'):
        self.msg = msg
    def __call__(self,fn):
        def newfn():
            print self.msg
            return fn()
        return newfn

@d('This is working')
def hello():
    print 'hello world !'

@d
def too_bad():
    print 'does not work'
```

In my code, only the use of decorator with parameter is working: How to proceed to have both working (with and without parameter)?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I found an example, you can use `@trace` or `@trace('msg1','msg2')`: nice!

```
def trace(*args):
    def _trace(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print enter_string
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            print exit_string
        return wrapper
    if len(args) == 1 and callable(args[0]):
        # No arguments, this is the decorator
        # Set default values for the arguments
        enter_string = 'entering'
        exit_string = 'exiting'
        return _trace(args[0])
    else:
        # This is just returning the decorator
        enter_string, exit_string = args
        return _trace
```

Comment: I guess it works for your case and would for similar cases. But what if the decorator's argument is actually a single callable? How would you differentiate between the decorated function and the argument?

Comment: @ksrini: Ignacio pointed that out in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3931654/355230) years ago.

Comment: You can also get around this by using keyword arguments (such as `@trace(default=...)`).

Comment: To avoid both this ambiguity *and* one unnecessary level of inner closure nesting, see [ForeverWintr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286571/foreverwintr)'s [single-line improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888158/making-decorators-with-optional-arguments#comment65959042_24617244) of [PatBenavente](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1901296/patbenavente)'s [similar answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24617244/2809027).

Answer (score 29):

If you want to take parameters to your decorator, you need to *always* call it as a function:

```
@d()
def func():
    pass
```

Otherwise, you need to try to detect the difference in parameters--in other words, you need to magically guess what the caller means.  Don't create an API that needs to guess; consistently say what you mean to begin with.

In other words, a function should either be a decorator, or a decorator factory; it shouldn't be both.

Note that if all you want to do is store a value, you don't need to write a class.

```
def d(msg='my default message'):
    def decorator(func):
        def newfn():
            print msg
            return func()
        return newfn
    return decorator

@d('This is working')
def hello():
    print 'hello world !'

@d()
def hello2():
    print 'also hello world'
```

Comment: This is probably a good advice, but it is not correct that a function can't do both, as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams explains. It is probably better to explain that in the answer.

Comment: @Muhammad: I didn't say it can't, I said it shouldn't.

Comment: I understand. But the value of the answer would be higher if this point is explained a bit better. Just saying.

Comment: This is a much simpler example to understand than the truly optional one provided by Eric. Python newbies might get lost in that one quicker than they would in this one.

Comment: I don't consider checking the type or number of arguments passed as "guessing", but do think that having to remember and use the decorator via `@d()` instead of usual `@d` in some case poor advice—including because it looks very weird/odd.

Comment: **No magical guesswork is required.** Violating Python conventions for no good reason is patently bad advice. Determining whether or not a decorator function is being called as a decorator or decorator factory trivially reduces to accepting only optional *keyword* rather than *positional* arguments (e.g., replacing `*args` with `**kwargs` in [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243483/eric)'s [rightfully accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3931903/2809027)). No ambiguity exists; ergo, there exists *no* reason to invent new calling conventions.

Comment: This is wrong: "you need to always call it as a function". Perhaps you wanted to say "should" instead of "need"?

Answer (score 19):

This would work.

```
def d(arg):
    if callable(arg):  # Assumes optional argument isn't.
        def newfn():
            print('my default message')
            return arg()
        return newfn
    else:
        def d2(fn):
            def newfn():
                print(arg)
                return fn()
            return newfn
        return d2

@d('This is working')
def hello():
    print('hello world !')

@d  # No explicit arguments will result in default message.
def hello2():
    print('hello2 world !')

@d('Applying it twice')
@d('Would also work')
def hello3():
    print('hello3 world !')

hello()
hello2()
hello3()
```

Output:

```
This is working
hello world !
my default message
hello2 world !
Applying it twice
Would also work
hello3 world !
```

If a decorator function `@`invocation isn't passed any explicit arguments, it is called with the function defined in the following  `def`. If it **is** passed arguments, then it is first called with them and then the result of **that** preliminary call (which must itself also be a callable) is called with the function being defined. Either way, the return value of the last or only call is bound to the defined function name.

Comment: Excellent, what an answer!

Answer (score 16):

If you don't mind relying on using named arguments, I made something similar to what you need:

```
def cached_property(method=None, get_attribute=lambda a: '_%s_cached' % (a,)):
    """
    Caches an object's attribute.

    Can be used in the following forms:
    @cached_property
    @cached_property()
    @cached_property(get_attribute=lambda x: 'bla')

    @param method: the method to memoizes
    @param get_attribute: a callable that should return the cached attribute
    @return a cached method
    """
    def decorator(method):
        def wrap(self):
            private_attribute = get_attribute(method.__name__)
            try:
                return getattr(self, private_attribute)
            except AttributeError:
                setattr(self, private_attribute, method(self))
                return getattr(self, private_attribute)
        return property(wrap)
    if method:
        # This was an actual decorator call, ex: @cached_property
        return decorator(method)
    else:
        # This is a factory call, ex: @cached_property()
        return decorator
```

This works because only one non keyword argument, the function decorated is passed to the decorator.

Notice that I also used the arguments passed to the decorated function, in this case 'self'.

Comment: TypeError: 'property' object is not callable

Answer (score 7):

You have to detect if the argument to the decorator is a function, and use a simple decorator in that case. And then you need to hope that you never need to pass only a function to the parametrized decorator.