# Decorator with arguments: avoid parenthesis when no arguments

Tags: python, logging, python-decorators

Below is my `@logged()` decorator maker. Here is roughly how it works:

1. It accepts a `logger` instance and a `disabled` flag.
2. If `disabled` is `False`, it outputs some logs before/after the decorated function.
3. If `disabled` is `True`, it outputs nothing and also suppresses the `logger` for the decorated function.

Both the `logger` and `disabled` arguments have their default values. However, when I want to use the default values, I still have to write empty parenthesis, like so:

```
@logged()
def foo():
    pass
```

*Is there any way to get rid of these empty parenthesis when I just want the default arguments?* Here is an example of what I would like to have:

```
@logged
def foo():
    pass

@logged(disabled=True)
def bar():
    pass
```

The code of the `@logged()` decorator maker:

```
import logging
import logging.config

from functools import wraps

def logged(logger=logging.getLogger('default'), disabled=False):
    '''
    Create a configured decorator that controls logging output of a function

    :param logger: the logger to send output to
    :param disabled: True if the logger should be disabled, False otherwise
    '''

    def logged_decorator(foo):
        '''
        Decorate a function and surround its call with enter/leave logs

        Produce logging output of the form:
        > enter foo
          ...
        > leave foo (returned value)
        '''

        @wraps(foo)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            was_disabled = logger.disabled

            # If the logger was not already disabled by something else, see if
            # it should be disabled by us. Important effect: if foo uses the
            # same logger, then any inner logging will be disabled as well.
            if not was_disabled:
                logger.disabled = disabled

            logger.debug(f'enter {foo.__qualname__}')

            result = foo(*args, **kwargs)

            logger.debug(f'leave {foo.__qualname__} ({result})')

            # Restore previous logger state:
            logger.disabled = was_disabled

            return result

        return wrapper

    return logged_decorator

logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(asctime)22s %(levelname)7s %(module)10s %(process)6d %(thread)15d %(message)s'
        }
        , 'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        }
    }
    , 'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG'
            , 'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
            , 'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'default': {
            'handlers': ['console']
            , 'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    }
})

@logged()
def foo():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of an if-else inside the decorator body:

```
def logged(func=None, *, disabled=False, logger=logging.default()):
    def logged_decorator(func):
        # stuff
        def wrapper(*args_, **kwargs):
            # stuff
            result = func(*args_, **kwargs)
            # stuff 
            return result
        return wrapper
    if func:
        return logged_decorator(func)
    else:
        return logged_decorator
```

The `(func=None, *, logger=..., disabled=False)` has an asterisk arg to denote the last 2 arguments as keyword-only arguments as any more arguments beside func are unpacked into the `*` which had no identifier in this case so are effectively 'lost'. These means you *must* use keyword arguments when using the decorator normally:

```
@logged(
    disabled=True,
    logged=logging.logger # ...
)
def foo(): pass
```

Or...

```
@logged
def bar(): pass
```

> See here: [How to build a decorator with optional parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3931627/9917694)

Answer (score 3):

I was incredibly annoyed by this and eventually wrote a library to solve this problem: [decopatch](https://smarie.github.io/python-decopatch/).

It supports two development styles: **nested** (like in python decorator factories) and **flat** (one less level of nesting). This is how your example would be implemented in flat mode:

```
from decopatch import function_decorator, DECORATED
from makefun import wraps

@function_decorator
def logged(disabled=False, logger=logging.getLogger('default'), func=DECORATED):

    # (1) create a signature-preserving wrapper
    @wraps(func)
    def _func_wrapper(*f_args, **f_kwargs):
        # stuff
        result = func(*f_args, **f_kwargs)
        # stuff
        return result

    # (2) return it
    return _func_wrapper
```

Note that I use [makefun.wraps](https://smarie.github.io/python-makefun/) instead of `functools.wraps` here so that the signature is fully preserved (the wrapper is not called at all if the arguments are invalid).

`decopatch` supports an additional development style, that I call **double-flat**, that is dedicated to creating signature-preserving function wrappers like this one. Your example would be implemented like this:

```
from decopatch import function_decorator, WRAPPED, F_ARGS, F_KWARGS

@function_decorator
def logged(disabled=False, logger=logging.getLogger('default'), 
           func=WRAPPED, f_args=F_ARGS, f_kwargs=F_KWARGS):
    # this is directly the signature-preserving wrapper
    # stuff
    result = func(*f_args, **f_kwargs)
    # stuff
    return result
```

You can check that both styles work as expected:

```
@logged(disabled=True)
def foo():
    pass

@logged
def bar():
    pass

foo()

bar()
```

Please check the [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-decopatch/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Or use partial (solution found in Python cookbook: 9.6)

```
from functools import wraps, partial

def foo(func=None, *, a=None, b=None):
    if func is None:
        return partial(foo, a=a, b=b)

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```