# Python decorator using wraps but name still changes

Tags: python, decorator

I'm having the following error handler (bypasser actually) decorator -

```
import functools

def exception_safe(*args):
        ErrList = tuple(args)
        def decorator(f):
                @functools.wraps(f)
                def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                        if ErrList:
                                try:
                                        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
                                        print(f'No error!')
                                        return result 
                                except ErrList as err:
                                        print(f'got error!')
                        else:
                                try:
                                        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
                                        print(f'No error!')
                                        return result 
                                except Exception as err:
                                        print(f'got error!')
                return wrapper
        return decorator
```

Even though I still get the next assertion error from my pytests, telling me that the function name is 'decorator':

[image: pytest stack]

What could be a reason for that? I literally tried everything..

Comment: There's an easier way for the record, using `suppress` you can tell it which errors to ignore - https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress. It'd make your wrapper a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

`exception_safe` needs to be given arguments, even if there aren't any:

```py
@exception_safe()
def function():
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931627/how-to-build-a-decorator-with-optional-parameters