# arguments in decorator not available in decorator scope?

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I have a decorator like this:

```
def dec(default):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            default = default or ['abc']
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

# use:
# decor = dec(default=['123'])
# @decor
# def something(default...
```

So I get this error, actually, my linter gives it to me before I even run the code, but I get it during testing too:

```
local variable 'default' defined in enclosing scope on line x referenced before assignment
```

What am I doing wrong in this decorator such that I can't use outside arguments it inside the wrapper?

Do I have to explicitly pass it to wrapper before `*args, **kwargs`? How am I supposed to do that if I return the decorator function itself without calling it? `return decorator`

other examples I can find don't seem to have this problem ([How to build a decorator with optional parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931627/how-to-build-a-decorator-with-optional-parameters))

is this a python 3 thing? those examples were mostly python 2. maybe in py3 I have to explicitly define them as `global default`?

it's cuz of `@wraps` isn't it? this example I found seems to work fine, but it doesn't use @wraps. though I need to use it.

```
def d(msg=None):
    def decorator(func):
        def newfn():
            msg = msg or 'abc'
            return func()
        return newfn
    return decorator

@d('This is working')
def hello():
    print 'hello world !'

@d()
def hello2():
    print 'also hello world'
```

what should I do?

Comment: Why is that line in the innermost function?  Shouldn't it be in the outermost scope? I'm confused about when and in what scopes you want to change the value of `default`

Comment: Your second example also throws the error.  (I noticed it has Python 2 syntax, are you using Python 2?)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Python3, that was an example I got from the link in the question. And yes, I see it has the same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes I think it does