# Decorators with parameters?

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments, decorator

I have a problem with the transfer of the variable `insurance_mode` by the decorator. I would do it by the following decorator statement:

```
@execute_complete_reservation(True)
def test_booking_gta_object(self):
    self.test_select_gta_object()
```

but unfortunately, this statement does not work. Perhaps maybe there is better way to solve this problem.

```
def execute_complete_reservation(test_case,insurance_mode):
    def inner_function(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.test_create_qsf_query()
        test_case(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.test_select_room_option()
        if insurance_mode:
            self.test_accept_insurance_crosseling()
        else:
            self.test_decline_insurance_crosseling()
        self.test_configure_pax_details()
        self.test_configure_payer_details

    return inner_function
```

Comment: Your example is not syntactically valid. `execute_complete_reservation` takes two parameters, but you're passing it one. Decorators are just syntactic sugar for wrapping functions inside other functions. See http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function for complete documentation.

Answer (score 1195, accepted):

The syntax for decorators with arguments is a bit different - the decorator with arguments should return a function that will *take a function* and return another function. So it should really return a normal decorator. A bit confusing, right? What I mean is:

```
def decorator_factory(argument):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            funny_stuff()
            something_with_argument(argument)
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            more_funny_stuff()
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

[Here](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845#decorator-functions-with-decorator-arguments) you can read more on the subject - it's also possible to implement this using callable objects and that is also explained there.

Comment: I just did this with lambdas all over the place.  (read: Python is awesome!) :)

Comment: I wonder why GVR didn't implement it by passing in the parameters as subsequent decorator arguments after 'function'. 

'Yo dawg I heard you like closures...' etcetera.

Comment: @MichelMüller, interesting! But it occurs to me that you'd need to adopt a convention. Would `function` be the first argument or last? I could make cases for either. The choice seems arbitrary, and so you'd have another random thing to memorize about the language. It's also weird that you'd "call" the function with a signature different from the one in the definition. I suppose that also happens with class methods -- but classes are full-blown language constructs with deep semantics, whereas decorators are just supposed to be syntactic sugar.

Comment: > Would function be the first argument or last?

Obviously first, since the parameters is a parameter list of variable length. 

>  It's also weird that you'd "call" the function with a signature different from the one in the definition.

As you point out, it would fit pretty well actually - it's pretty much analogous to how a class method is called. To make it more clear, you could have something like decorator(self_func, param1, ...) convention. 

But note: I'm not advocating for any change here, Python is too far down the road for that and we can see how breaking changes have worked out..

Comment: you forgot VERY USEFUL functools.wraps for decorating wrapper :)

Comment: It works but I am sometimes having problems with `argument` that is not seen in the inner `wrapper` function (2.7.6, osx apple version). Do you know if this issue is a known issue?

Comment: You forgot about return when calling function, i.e. 
`return function(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Maybe obvious, but just in case: you need to use this decorator as `@decorator()` and not just `@decorator`, even if you have only optional arguments.

Comment: To make this complete, you may also want to add `@functools.wraps(function)` above the `def wrapper...` line.

Comment: Although this is the solution, it really does'nt seem elegant or pythonic. I always viewed decorators as like object methods, which pass in `self` as an argument automatically when called. Having an additional function layer to handle arguments just does not feel right

Comment: @Titan I'd say it's very pythoninc.  The nested methods is to allow you to define decorators separate to using them.  It makes it possible to have two steps `x=decorator_factory(foo)` `@x; def ...` as well as the more common single step `@decorator_factory(foo); def ...`.  Though it's less common, it is used and very useful.

Comment: I'm wondering what the canonical nomenclature is for this case of decorator with arguments. I've heard, for the nested functions from outer to inner, of: `<name>`, `decorator_<name>`, `wrapper` (for `<name>`, the name of your decorator). Any contradicting or stronger conventions?

Answer (score 531):

**Edit** : for an in-depth understanding of the mental model of decorators, take a look at [this](https://youtu.be/MjHpMCIvwsY) awesome Pycon Talk. well worth the 30 minutes.

One way of thinking about decorators with arguments is

```
@decorator
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

translates to

```
foo = decorator(foo)
```

So if the decorator had arguments,

```
@decorator_with_args(arg)
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

translates to

```
foo = decorator_with_args(arg)(foo)
```

`decorator_with_args` is a function which accepts a custom argument and which returns the actual decorator (that will be applied to the decorated function).

I use a simple trick with partials to make my decorators easy

```
from functools import partial

def _pseudo_decor(fun, argument):
    def ret_fun(*args, **kwargs):
        #do stuff here, for eg.
        print ("decorator arg is %s" % str(argument))
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)
    return ret_fun

real_decorator = partial(_pseudo_decor, argument=arg)

@real_decorator
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

*Update:*

Above, `foo` becomes `real_decorator(foo)`

One effect of decorating a function is that the name `foo` is overridden upon decorator declaration. `foo` is "overridden" by whatever is returned by `real_decorator`. In this case, a new function object.

All of `foo`'s metadata is overridden, notably docstring and function name.

```
>>> print(foo)
<function _pseudo_decor.<locals>.ret_fun at 0x10666a2f0>
```

[functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) gives us a convenient method to "lift" the docstring and name to the returned function.

```
from functools import partial, wraps

def _pseudo_decor(fun, argument):
    # magic sauce to lift the name and doc of the function
    @wraps(fun)
    def ret_fun(*args, **kwargs):
        # pre function execution stuff here, for eg.
        print("decorator argument is %s" % str(argument))
        returned_value =  fun(*args, **kwargs)
        # post execution stuff here, for eg.
        print("returned value is %s" % returned_value)
        return returned_value

    return ret_fun

real_decorator1 = partial(_pseudo_decor, argument="some_arg")
real_decorator2 = partial(_pseudo_decor, argument="some_other_arg")

@real_decorator1
def bar(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

>>> print(bar)
<function __main__.bar(*args, **kwargs)>

>>> bar(1,2,3, k="v", x="z")
decorator argument is some_arg
returned value is None
```

Comment: Your answer perfectly explained the inherent orthogonality of the decorator, thank you

Comment: Could you add `@functools.wraps`?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D , I've updated the post with an example with `functool.wraps`. Adding it in the example may confuse readers further.

Comment: What is `arg` here!?

Comment: @StefanFalk `arg` is just a variable name, with the value that you'd use for creating the `real_decorator` out of  `_pseudo_decor`

Comment: How will you pass argument passed to `bar` to the argument of `real_decorator` ?

Comment: @ChangZhao as described above, even though you use the name `bar` in the code after the declaration, python "points" the name `bar` to the result of `real_decorator(bar)` so any arguments that you pass while calling `bar(arg1, arg2..)` is in fact interpreted as `real_decorator(bar)(arg1, arg2,..)`

Comment: how will that work with partial ? because you are passing arg !

Comment: Try it out for yourself. hopefully this piece of code is self-explanatory. https://repl.it/@sreedom/SpotlessTastyScreencast

Comment: So how will it work when you don't know `arg` until it is time to actually run the function? aka you want to surround a string with an HTML tag but the used tag can be different every time (or even user defined)?

Comment: In `numba` library, there's `@jit(nopython=True)` expression. How's that possible then? In this scenario, I don't see how `numba` is casually just getting an argument.

Comment: I've edited the example with `wraps` to be clearer in the use of `arg`.

Comment: why wouldn't "foo = decorator_with_args(arg)(foo)" be "foo = decorator_with_args(foo(arg))" instead?

Comment: @jouell, because python will execute the `@decorator_with_args(arg)` first , the result of that will take in the function object created by the `def` statement.

Comment: @srj It actually is `foo = decorator_with_args(foo)(arg)`.  `decorator_with_args(foo)` will return the wrapper function. This wrapper function needs 'args' as arguments. Hence `wrapper(arg)` will be executed next

Comment: For a solution with more flexibility:

`def decor_with_argument(argument: str): return partial(_pseudo_decor, argument=argument)`

In action:

`@decor_with_argument(argument="some_arg")`

Answer (score 167):

Here is a slightly modified version of [t.dubrownik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5929165/1400991). Why?

1. As a general template, you should return the return value from the original function.
2. This changes the name of the function, which could affect other decorators / code.

So use [`@functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
from functools import wraps

def create_decorator(argument):
    def decorator(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            funny_stuff()
            something_with_argument(argument)
            retval = function(*args, **kwargs)
            more_funny_stuff()
            return retval
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Comment: I did exactly that, but on AWS lambdas with flask it doesn't work: python 3.8 returns this error:
`AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: authorization_required_wrapper`

Comment: this is my favorite answer here as wraps is critical.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, took me some time to...*wrap* my head around this concept...ba dum tsk... lol. So the key concept here for me was that this is 3 layers deep. Found some more related info: https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#decorators-with-arguments

Comment: As @Jennings says this link is better at explaining this. The above code is the very very minimal amount to show the answer, but doesn't explain enough about what's going on. https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#defining-decorators-with-arguments

Answer (score 125):

I'd like to show an idea which is IMHO quite elegant. The solution proposed by t.dubrownik shows a pattern which is always the same: you need the three-layered wrapper regardless of what the decorator does.

So I thought this is a job for a meta-decorator, that is, a decorator for decorators. As a decorator is a function, it actually works as a regular decorator with arguments:

```
def parametrized(dec):
    def layer(*args, **kwargs):
        def repl(f):
            return dec(f, *args, **kwargs)
        return repl
    return layer
```

This can be applied to a regular decorator in order to add parameters. So for instance, say we have the decorator which doubles the result of a function:

```
def double(f):
    def aux(*xs, **kws):
        return 2 * f(*xs, **kws)
    return aux

@double
def function(a):
    return 10 + a

print function(3)    # Prints 26, namely 2 * (10 + 3)
```

With `@parametrized` we can build a generic `@multiply` decorator having a parameter

```
@parametrized
def multiply(f, n):
    def aux(*xs, **kws):
        return n * f(*xs, **kws)
    return aux

@multiply(2)
def function(a):
    return 10 + a

print function(3)    # Prints 26

@multiply(3)
def function_again(a):
    return 10 + a

print function(3)          # Keeps printing 26
print function_again(3)    # Prints 39, namely 3 * (10 + 3)
```

Conventionally the first parameter of a *parametrized* decorator is the function, while the remaining arguments will correspond to the parameter of the parametrized decorator.

An interesting usage example could be a type-safe assertive decorator:

```
import itertools as it

@parametrized
def types(f, *types):
    def rep(*args):
        for a, t, n in zip(args, types, it.count()):
            if type(a) is not t:
                raise TypeError('Value %d has not type %s. %s instead' %
                    (n, t, type(a))
                )
        return f(*args)
    return rep

@types(str, int)  # arg1 is str, arg2 is int
def string_multiply(text, times):
    return text * times

print(string_multiply('hello', 3))    # Prints hellohellohello
print(string_multiply(3, 3))          # Fails miserably with TypeError
```

A final note: here I'm not using `functools.wraps` for the wrapper functions,  but I would recommend using it all the times.

Comment: Didn't use this exactly, but helped me get my head around the concept :) Thanks!

Comment: I tried this and had some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734219/flask-error-with-two-parameterized-functions).

Comment: @Jeff could you share with us the kind of issues you had?

Comment: I had it linked on my question, and I did figure it out... I needed to call `@wraps` in mine for my particular case.

Comment: Aha! I suspected that, as it was the only possible fault that I could spot. Indeed I changed my answer and appended a mention about `wraps`. True story :)

Comment: It works but I have trouble getting my head around it. How would one translate the decorators' syntactic sugar into mundane calls in that case? Keeping with your example would it be: `function = parametrized(multiply(function, 2))` and then calling `function(3)` to get `26`? It doesn't work when I try it with my analogues

Comment: @o'rety I'm a bit confused by your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Oh boy, I lost a whole day on this. Thankfully, I came around [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/4465708) (which incidentally could be the best answer ever created on the whole internet). They too use your `@parametrized` trick. The problem I had was I forgot the `@` syntax **equals actual calls** (somehow I knew that and didn't know that at the same time as you can gather from my question). So if you want to translate `@` syntax into *mundane calls* to check how it works, you better comment it out temporarily first or you'd end up calling it twice and getting mumbojumbo results

Comment: It's cool on one hand but I don't understand the reason for having 3 methods encapsulating to each other. Namely I don't understand what on the earth repl() does, is it just a trick with scopes and param numbers?

Comment: `repl` stands for replacement.  When I name it repl it means that it will effectively take the place of another function. Assuming that you are talking about the `parametrized` decorator, `layer` will replace the decorated decorator. The `dec` parameter of `parametrized` is the decorator we are going to replace with `layer`. Decorators take functions as parameter, and indeed we pass `f` to `dec`.  So, ultimately, `repl` is what replaces `dec`, and works by applying the decorator `dec` so that it replaces `f`.  I hope that this comment makes it clearer, but I myself have to read it many times.

Comment: This is the most handy approach in Python that I have seen. Very cool and easy to use! All thumbs up!  :-)

Answer (score 49):

Writing a decorator that works with and without parameter is a challenge because Python expects completely different behavior in these two cases! Many answers have tried to work around this and below is an improvement of [answer by @norok2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57268935/5218354). Specifically, this variation eliminates the use of `locals()`.

Following the same example as given by @norok2:

```
import functools

def multiplying(f_py=None, factor=1):
    assert callable(f_py) or f_py is None
    def _decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return factor * func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return _decorator(f_py) if callable(f_py) else _decorator


@multiplying
def summing(x): return sum(x)

print(summing(range(10)))
# 45


@multiplying()
def summing(x): return sum(x)

print(summing(range(10)))
# 45


@multiplying(factor=10)
def summing(x): return sum(x)

print(summing(range(10)))
# 450
```

[Play with this code](https://repl.it/@sytelus/decorator).

The catch is that the user must supply key,value pairs of parameters instead of positional parameters and the first parameter is reserved.

Comment: This is freaking genius.

Comment: Please expound on " Python expects completely different behavior in these two cases"

Comment: How about changing the multiplying function's return from `return _decorator(f_py) if callable(f_py) else _decorator` to `return _decorator(f_py) if f_py else _decorator` or `return _decorator if f_py is None else _decorator(f_py)` since you've already asserted that it's either a callable or None. This should be "more efficient" than calling `callable` a second time.

Comment: This is the pattern I was looking for - a decorator that can be used both with and without args.  The examples I have experience with are Click (the command-builder from Flask project) and Dramatiq (the task queue alternative to Celery).  I particularly recommend checking out Dramatiq's implementation: https://github.com/Bogdanp/dramatiq/blob/master/dramatiq/actor.py

Comment: Works a treat, i also needed to use @overload to be compatible with typing checks, this solution solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077656/how-to-type-annotate-a-decorator-that-has-an-optional-parameter/55195951#55195951

Answer (score 44):

I presume your problem is passing arguments to your decorator. This is a little tricky and not straightforward.

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
class MyDec(object):
    def __init__(self,flag):
        self.flag = flag
    def __call__(self, original_func):
        decorator_self = self
        def wrappee( *args, **kwargs):
            print 'in decorator before wrapee with flag ',decorator_self.flag
            original_func(*args,**kwargs)
            print 'in decorator after wrapee with flag ',decorator_self.flag
        return wrappee

@MyDec('foo de fa fa')
def bar(a,b,c):
    print 'in bar',a,b,c

bar('x','y','z')
```

Prints:

```
in decorator before wrapee with flag  foo de fa fa
in bar x y z
in decorator after wrapee with flag  foo de fa fa
```

[See Bruce Eckel's article for more details.](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808#function-decorators)

Comment: Beware of decorator classes. They don't work on methods unless you manually reinvent the logic of instancemethod descriptors.

Comment: delnan, care to elaborate?  I've only had to use this pattern once, so I haven't hit any of the pitfalls yet.

Comment: @RossRogers My guess is that @delnan is referring to things like `__name__` which an instance of the decorator class won't have?

Comment: @jamesc That too, though that's relatively easy to solve. The specific case I was referring to was `class Foo: @MyDec(...) def method(self, ...): blah` which does not work because `Foo().method` won't be a bound method and won't pass `self` automatically. This too can be fixed, by making `MyDec` a descriptor and creating bound methods in `__get__`, but it's more involved and much less obvious. In the end, decorator classes are not as convenient as they seem.

Comment: @delnan I'd like to see this caveat featured more prominently. I'm hitting it and am interested in seeing a solution that DOES work (more involved an less obvious though it may be).

Comment: This seems like a great answer but there are some steps here  I do not understand. Why copy self into decorator_self. Is this to get around the issue mentioned above?

Comment: I don't think the `decorator_self` is necessary anymore.  It _was_ because I had `self` as the first parameter of `wrapee` way back when I was experimenting.  Try it with out it, just using `self` and not aliasing `self` to `decorator_self`

Answer (score 25):

```
def decorator(argument):
    def real_decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args):
            for arg in args:
                assert type(arg)==int,f'{arg} is not an interger'
            result = function(*args)
            result = result*argument
            return result
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator
```

Usage of the decorator

```
@decorator(2)
def adder(*args):
    sum=0
    for i in args:
        sum+=i
    return sum
```

Then the

```
adder(2,3)
```

produces

```
10
```

but

```
adder('hi',3)
```

produces

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-242a8feb1cc4> in <module>
----> 1 adder('hi',3)

<ipython-input-140-d3420c248ebd> in wrapper(*args)
      3         def wrapper(*args):
      4             for arg in args:
----> 5                 assert type(arg)==int,f'{arg} is not an interger'
      6             result = function(*args)
      7             result = result*argument

AssertionError: hi is not an interger
```

Comment: Of all the posts here, this answer proved the most useful for my understanding of how the argument is passed and handled.

Answer (score 24):

This is a template for a function decorator that does not require `()` if no parameters are to be given and supports both positional and keyword parameters (but requires cheching on `locals()` to find out if the first parameter is the function to be decorated or not):

```py
import functools


def decorator(x_or_func=None, *decorator_args, **decorator_kws):
    def _decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kws):
            if 'x_or_func' not in locals() \
                    or callable(x_or_func) \
                    or x_or_func is None:
                x = ...  # <-- default `x` value
            else:
                x = x_or_func
            return func(*args, **kws)

        return wrapper

    return _decorator(x_or_func) if callable(x_or_func) else _decorator
```

an example of this is given below:

```py
def multiplying(factor_or_func=None):
    def _decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if 'factor_or_func' not in locals() \
                    or callable(factor_or_func) \
                    or factor_or_func is None:
                factor = 1
            else:
                factor = factor_or_func
            return factor * func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return _decorator(factor_or_func) if callable(factor_or_func) else _decorator


@multiplying
def summing(x): return sum(x)

print(summing(range(10)))
# 45


@multiplying()
def summing(x): return sum(x)

print(summing(range(10)))
# 45


@multiplying(10)
def summing(x): return sum(x)

print(summing(range(10)))
# 450
```

---

Alternatively, if one does not need positional arguments, one can relax the need for checking on the first parameter within the `wrapper()` (thus removing the need to use `locals()`):

```py
import functools


def decorator(func_=None, **decorator_kws):
    def _decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kws):
            return func(*args, **kws)
        return wrapper

    if callable(func_):
        return _decorator(func_)
    elif func_ is None:
        return _decorator
    else:
        raise RuntimeWarning("Positional arguments are not supported.")
```

an example of this is given below:

```
import functools


def multiplying(func_=None, factor=1):
    def _decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return factor * func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    if callable(func_):
        return _decorator(func_)
    elif func_ is None:
        return _decorator
    else:
        raise RuntimeWarning("Positional arguments are not supported.")


@multiplying
def summing(x): return sum(x)

print(summing(range(10)))
# 45


@multiplying()
def summing(x): return sum(x)

print(summing(range(10)))
# 45


@multiplying(factor=10)
def summing(x): return sum(x)

print(summing(range(10)))
# 450


@multiplying(10)
def summing(x): return sum(x)
print(summing(range(10)))
# RuntimeWarning Traceback (most recent call last)
#    ....
# RuntimeWarning: Positional arguments are not supported.
```

(partially reworked from [@ShitalShah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60832711/5218354))

Comment: Note also that `factor_or_func` (or any other parameter) [should never gets reassigned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57691284/5218354) in `wrapper()`.

Comment: Why do you need to check in `locals()`?

Comment: @ShitalShah that covers the case where the decorator is used without `()`.

Comment: Works a treat, i also needed to use @overload to be compatible with typing checks, this solution solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077656/how-to-type-annotate-a-decorator-that-has-an-optional-parameter/55195951#55195951

Answer (score 18):

***Simple as this***

```
def real_decorator(any_number_of_arguments):
   def pseudo_decorator(function_to_be_decorated):

       def real_wrapper(function_arguments):
           print(function_arguments)
           result = function_to_be_decorated(any_number_of_arguments)
           return result

       return real_wrapper
   return pseudo_decorator
```

***Now***

```
@real_decorator(any_number_of_arguments)
def some_function(function_arguments):
        return "Any"
```

Comment: Note that this will not work similiar to the normal decorator, if the `any_number_of_arguments` is optional arg, you still have to write `()` in the end of the decorator.

Comment: The question pertains specifically to decorators with parameters and does not concern optional parameters.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

- Here we ran display info twice with two different names and two different ages.
- Now every time we ran display info, our decorators also added the functionality of printing out a line before and a line after that wrapped function.

```py
def decorator_function(original_function):
    def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Executed Before', original_function.__name__)
        result = original_function(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Executed After', original_function.__name__, '\n')
        return result
    return wrapper_function


@decorator_function
def display_info(name, age):
    print('display_info ran with arguments ({}, {})'.format(name, age))


display_info('Mr Bean', 66)
display_info('MC Jordan', 57)
```

output:

```sh
Executed Before display_info
display_info ran with arguments (Mr Bean, 66)
Executed After display_info 

Executed Before display_info
display_info ran with arguments (MC Jordan, 57)
Executed After display_info
```

- So now let's go ahead and get our decorator function to accept arguments.
- For example let's say that I wanted a customizable prefix to all of these print statements within the wrapper.
- Now this would be a good candidate for an argument to the decorator.
- The argument that we pass in will be that prefix. Now in order to do, this we're just going to add another outer layer to our decorator, so I'm going to call this a function a prefix decorator.

```py
def prefix_decorator(prefix):
    def decorator_function(original_function):
        def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
            print(prefix, 'Executed Before', original_function.__name__)
            result = original_function(*args, **kwargs)
            print(prefix, 'Executed After', original_function.__name__, '\n')
            return result
        return wrapper_function
    return decorator_function


@prefix_decorator('LOG:')
def display_info(name, age):
    print('display_info ran with arguments ({}, {})'.format(name, age))


display_info('Mr Bean', 66)
display_info('MC Jordan', 57)
```

output:

```py
LOG: Executed Before display_info
display_info ran with arguments (Mr Bean, 66)
LOG: Executed After display_info 

LOG: Executed Before display_info
display_info ran with arguments (MC Jordan, 57)
LOG: Executed After display_info
```

- Now we have that `LOG:` prefix before our print statements in our wrapper function and you can change this any time that you want.

Comment: The GIF with code is cool to look at, but difficult to read. I love when the text I'm trying to read doesn't disappear in front of my eyes :D

Comment: Everyone has the right to look, someone learns from what they see and uses it because they understand the purpose, and someone may not see the point of everything and looks for criticism, so it's all about the look. For example, as I do not understand your comment, i.e. its point. :D

Comment: My point is, that the code in the animated GIF is difficult to read because _it keeps disappearing while I'm reading it_, so it's quite difficult to "learn from what I see". For example, the last line stays on screen for *less than 0.3 seconds*. `someone may not see the point of everything and looks for criticism` I don't see the point of creating an animated GIF of the code line by line, instead of just pasting it in the answer as a code block. I'm not "looking for criticism" for the sake of it. I read the answer and used comments to suggest improvements which is literally their purpose.

Answer (score 7):

Great answers above. This one also illustrates `@wraps`, which takes the doc string and function name from the original function and applies it to the new wrapped version:

```
from functools import wraps

def decorator_func_with_args(arg1, arg2):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Before orginal function with decorator args:", arg1, arg2)
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            print("Ran after the orginal function")
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@decorator_func_with_args("foo", "bar")
def hello(name):
    """A function which prints a greeting to the name provided.
    """
    print('hello ', name)
    return 42

print("Starting script..")
x = hello('Bob')
print("The value of x is:", x)
print("The wrapped functions docstring is:", hello.__doc__)
print("The wrapped functions name is:", hello.__name__)
```

Prints:

```
Starting script..
Before orginal function with decorator args: foo bar
hello  Bob
Ran after the orginal function
The value of x is: 42
The wrapped functions docstring is: A function which prints a greeting to the name provided.
The wrapped functions name is: hello
```

Answer (score 4):

In my instance, I decided to solve this via a one-line lambda to create a new decorator function:

```
def finished_message(function, message="Finished!"):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        output = function(*args,**kwargs)
        print(message)
        return output

    return wrapper

@finished_message
def func():
    pass

my_finished_message = lambda f: finished_message(f, "All Done!")

@my_finished_message
def my_func():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func()
    my_func()
```

When executed, this prints:

```
Finished!
All Done!
```

Perhaps not as extensible as other solutions, but worked for me.

Comment: This works. Although yes, this makes it hard to set the value to the decorator.

Answer (score 4):

It is well known that the following two pieces of code are nearly equivalent:

```
@dec
def foo():
    pass    foo = dec(foo)

############################################
foo = dec(foo)
```

A common mistake is to think that `@` simply hides the leftmost argument.

```
@dec(1, 2, 3)
def foo():
    pass    
###########################################
foo = dec(foo, 1, 2, 3)
```

It would be much easier to write decorators if the above is how `@` worked. Unfortunately, that’s not the way things are done.

---

Consider a decorator `Wait`which haults 
program execution for a few seconds.
If you don't pass in a Wait-time
then the default value is 1 seconds.
Use-cases are shown below.

```
##################################################
@Wait
def print_something(something):
    print(something)

##################################################
@Wait(3)
def print_something_else(something_else):
    print(something_else)

##################################################
@Wait(delay=3)
def print_something_else(something_else):
    print(something_else)
```

When `Wait` has an argument, such as `@Wait(3)`, then the call `Wait(3)`
is executed ***before*** anything else happens.

That is, the following two pieces of code are equivalent

```
@Wait(3)
def print_something_else(something_else):
    print(something_else)

###############################################
return_value = Wait(3)
@return_value
def print_something_else(something_else):
    print(something_else)
```

This is a problem.

```
if `Wait` has no arguments:
    `Wait` is the decorator.
else: # `Wait` receives arguments
    `Wait` is not the decorator itself.
    Instead, `Wait` ***returns*** the decorator
```

---

One solution is shown below:

Let us begin by creating the following class, `DelayedDecorator`:

```
class DelayedDecorator:
    def __init__(i, cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Delayed Decorator __init__", cls, args, kwargs)
        i._cls = cls
        i._args = args
        i._kwargs = kwargs
    def __call__(i, func):
        print("Delayed Decorator __call__", func)
        if not (callable(func)):
            import io
            with io.StringIO() as ss:
                print(
                    "If only one input, input must be callable",
                    "Instead, received:",
                    repr(func),
                    sep="\n",
                    file=ss
                )
                msg = ss.getvalue()
            raise TypeError(msg)
        return i._cls(func, *i._args, **i._kwargs)
```

Now we can write things like:

```
 dec = DelayedDecorator(Wait, delay=4)
 @dec
 def delayed_print(something):
    print(something)
```

Note that:

- `dec` does not not accept multiple arguments.
- `dec` only accepts the function to be wrapped.

  import inspect
  class PolyArgDecoratorMeta(type):
      def **call**(Wait, *args, **kwargs):
          try:
              arg_count = len(args)
              if (arg_count == 1):
                  if callable(args[0]):
                      SuperClass = inspect.getmro(PolyArgDecoratorMeta)[1]
                      r = SuperClass.**call**(Wait, args[0])
                  else:
                      r = DelayedDecorator(Wait, *args, **kwargs)
              else:
                  r = DelayedDecorator(Wait, *args, **kwargs)
          finally:
              pass
          return r

  import time
  class Wait(metaclass=PolyArgDecoratorMeta):
      def **init**(i, func, delay = 2):
          i._func = func
          i._delay = delay

  ```
  def __call__(i, *args, **kwargs):
      time.sleep(i._delay)
      r = i._func(*args, **kwargs)
      return r
  ```

The following two pieces of code are equivalent:

```
@Wait
def print_something(something):
     print (something)

##################################################

def print_something(something):
    print(something)
print_something = Wait(print_something)
```

We can print `"something"` to the console very slowly, as follows:

```
print_something("something")

#################################################
@Wait(delay=1)
def print_something_else(something_else):
    print(something_else)

##################################################
def print_something_else(something_else):
    print(something_else)

dd = DelayedDecorator(Wait, delay=1)
print_something_else = dd(print_something_else)

##################################################

print_something_else("something")
```

---

### Final Notes

It may look like a lot of code, but you don't have to write the classes `DelayedDecorator` and `PolyArgDecoratorMeta` every-time. The only code you have to personally write something like as follows, which is fairly short:

```
from PolyArgDecoratorMeta import PolyArgDecoratorMeta
import time
class Wait(metaclass=PolyArgDecoratorMeta):
 def __init__(i, func, delay = 2):
     i._func = func
     i._delay = delay

 def __call__(i, *args, **kwargs):
     time.sleep(i._delay)
     r = i._func(*args, **kwargs)
     return r
```

Answer (score 4):

the decorator with arguments should return a function that will take a function and return another function you can do that

```
def decorator_factory(argument):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            """
                add somhting
            """
            return  function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

or you can use partial from functools module

```
def decorator(function =None,*,argument ):
        if function is None :
            return partial(decorator,argument=argument)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            """
                add somhting
            """
            return  function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

in the second option just make sure you pass the arguments like this :

```
@decorator(argument = 'args')
def func():
    pass
```

Comment: Most elegant solution IMHO, found it in the [Python 3 Metaprogramming](http://dabeaz.com/py3meta/index.html) tutorial by David Beazley.

Answer (score 4):

For example, I created **`multiply()`** below which can accept one or no argument or no parentheses from the decorator and I created `sum()` below:

```py
from numbers import Number

def multiply(num=1):
    def _multiply(func):
        def core(*args, **kwargs):
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if isinstance(num, Number):
                return result * num
            else:
                return result
        return core
    if callable(num):
        return _multiply(num)
    else:
        return _multiply

def sum(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
```

Now, I put `@multiply(5)` on `sum()`, then called `sum(4, 6)` as shown below:

```py
# (4 + 6) x 5 = 50

@multiply(5) # Here
def sum(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

result = sum(4, 6)
print(result)
```

Then, I could get the result below:

```
50
```

Next, I put `@multiply()` on `sum()`, then called `sum(4, 6)` as shown below:

```py
# (4 + 6) x 1 = 10

@multiply() # Here
def sum(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
    
result = sum(4, 6)
print(result)
```

Or, I put `@multiply` on `sum()`, then called `sum(4, 6)` as shown below:

```py
# 4 + 6 = 10

@multiply # Here
def sum(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
    
result = sum(4, 6)
print(result)
```

Then, I could get the result below:

```
10
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a decorator that can be called in a variety of ways (tested in python3.7):

```py
import functools


def my_decorator(*args_or_func, **decorator_kwargs):

    def _decorator(func):

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            if not args_or_func or callable(args_or_func[0]):
                # Here you can set default values for positional arguments
                decorator_args = ()
            else:
                decorator_args = args_or_func

            print(
                "Available inside the wrapper:",
                decorator_args, decorator_kwargs
            )

            # ...
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            # ...

            return result

        return wrapper

    return _decorator(args_or_func[0]) \
        if args_or_func and callable(args_or_func[0]) else _decorator


@my_decorator
def func_1(arg): print(arg)

func_1("test")
# Available inside the wrapper: () {}
# test


@my_decorator()
def func_2(arg): print(arg)

func_2("test")
# Available inside the wrapper: () {}
# test


@my_decorator("any arg")
def func_3(arg): print(arg)

func_3("test")
# Available inside the wrapper: ('any arg',) {}
# test


@my_decorator("arg_1", 2, [3, 4, 5], kwarg_1=1, kwarg_2="2")
def func_4(arg): print(arg)

func_4("test")
# Available inside the wrapper: ('arg_1', 2, [3, 4, 5]) {'kwarg_1': 1, 'kwarg_2': '2'}
# test
```

PS thanks to user **@norok2** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57268935/5353484

**UPD** Decorator for validating arguments and/or result of functions and methods of a class against annotations. Can be used in synchronous or asynchronous version: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/valdec

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a function

```
def f(*args):
    print(*args)
```

And you want to add a decorator that accepts arguments to it like this:

```
@decorator(msg='hello')
def f(*args):
    print(*args)
```

This means Python will modify `f` as follows:

```
f = decorator(msg='hello')(f)
```

So, the return of the part `decorator(msg='hello')` should be a wrapper function that accepts the function f and returns the modified function. then you can execute the modified function.

```
def decorator(**kwargs):
    def wrap(f):
        def modified_f(*args):
            print(kwargs['msg']) # use passed arguments to the decorator
            return f(*args)
        return modified_f
    return wrap
```

So, when you call `f`, it is like you are doing:
`decorator(msg='hello')(f)(args)`
=== `wrap(f)(args)` === `modified_f(args)`
but `modified_f` has access to `kwargs` passed to the decorator

The output of

```
f(1,2,3)
```

will be:

```
hello
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

define this "decoratorize function" to generate customized decorator function:

```
def decoratorize(FUN, **kw):
    def foo(*args, **kws):
        return FUN(*args, **kws, **kw)
    return foo
```

use it this way:

```
    @decoratorize(FUN, arg1 = , arg2 = , ...)
    def bar(...):
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Flask example using decorators with parameters. Suppose we have a route '/user/name' and we want to map to his home page.

```
def matchR(dirPath):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(msg):
            if dirPath[0:6] == '/user/':
                print(f"User route '{dirPath}' match, calling func {func}")
                name = dirPath[6:]
                return func(msg2=name, msg3=msg)
            else:
                print(f"Input dirPath '{dirPath}' does not match route '/user/'")
                return
        return  wrapper
    return decorator

#@matchR('/Morgan_Hills')
@matchR('/user/Morgan_Hills')
def home(**kwMsgs):
    for arg in kwMsgs:
        if arg == 'msg2':
            print(f"In home({arg}): Hello {kwMsgs[arg]}, welcome home!")
        if arg == 'msg3':
            print(f"In home({arg}): {kwMsgs[arg]}")

home('This is your profile rendered as in index.html.')
```

Output:

```
User route '/user/Morgan_Hills' match, calling func <function home at 0x000001DD5FDCD310>
In home(msg2): Hello Morgan_Hills, welcome home!
In home(msg3): This is your profile rendered as in index.html.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use case for a curried function.

Curried functions essentially delay a function from being called until all inputs have been supplied.

This can be used for a variety of things like wrappers or functional programming. In this case lets create a wrapper that takes in inputs.

I will use a simple package [pamda](https://connor-makowski.github.io/pamda/pamda_core.html) that includes a curry function for python. This can be used as a wrapper for other functions.

Install Pamda:

```sh
pip install pamda
```

Create a simple curried decorator function with two inputs:

```py
@pamda.curry()
def my_decorator(input, func):
    print ("Executing Decorator")
    print(f"input:{input}")
    return func
```

Apply your decorator with the first input supplied to your target function:

```py
@my_decorator('Hi!')
def foo(input):
    print('Executing Foo!')
    print(f"input:{input}")
```

Execute your wrapped function:

```py
x=foo('Bye!')
```

Putting everything together:

```py
from pamda import pamda

@pamda.curry()
def my_decorator(input, func):
    print ("Executing Decorator")
    print(f"input:{input}")
    return func

@my_decorator('Hi!')
def foo(input):
    print('Executing Foo!')
    print(f"input:{input}")

x=foo('Bye!')
```

Would give:

```py
Executing Decorator
input:Hi!
Executing Foo!
input:Bye!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a **working, real-world example, with usage examples** of the most generic use-case can be valuable here.

---

The following is a decorator for functions, which prints to log upon entering and exiting the function.

Parameters control weather or not to print input and output values, log level and so on.

```
import logging 
from functools import wraps


def log_in_out(logger=logging.get_logger(), is_print_input=True, is_print_output=True, is_method=True, log_level=logging.DEBUG):
    """
    @param logger-
    @param is_print_input- toggle printing input arguments
    @param is_print_output- toggle printing output values
    @param is_method- True for methods, False for functions. Makes "self" not printed in case of is_print_input==True
    @param log_level-

    @returns- a decorator that logs to logger when entering or exiting the decorated function.
    Don't uglify your code!
    """

    def decor(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if is_print_input:
                logger.log(
                    msg=f"Entered {fn.__name__} with args={args[1:] if is_method else args}, kwargs={kwargs}",
                    level=log_level
                )
            else:
                logger.log(
                    msg=f"Entered {fn.__name__}",
                    level=log_level
                )

            result = fn(*args, **kwargs)

            if is_print_output and result is not None:
                logger.log(
                    msg=f"Exited {fn.__name__} with result {result}",
                    level=log_level,
                )
            else:
                logger.log(
                    msg=f"Exited {fn.__name__}",
                    level=log_level
                )

            return result

        return wrapper

    return decor
```

usage:

```
 @log_in_out(is_method=False, is_print_input=False)
    def foo(a, b=5):
        return 3, a
```

`foo(2)` --> prints

> Entered foo
> Exited foo with result (3, 2)

```
    class A():
        @log_in_out(is_print_output=False)
        def bar(self, c, m, y):
            return c, 6
```

`a = A()`
`a.bar(1, 2, y=3)` --> prints

> Entered bar with args=(1, 2), kwargs={y:3}
> Exited bar

Answer (score 0):

It worth checking [Making decorators with optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888158/making-decorators-with-optional-arguments) and its duplicates for more comprehensive answers.

A generic decorator skeleton code with comments and tests which tries to summarize all possible use cases:

```py
from functools import wraps


def my_decorator(*args_or_func, **decorator_kwargs):
    """Originally from:
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters/65512042#65512042
    with hints from:
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888158/making-decorators-with-optional-arguments/24617244#24617244"""
    def _decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)  # See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Do things before executing the function
            print("Available inside the wrapper:", decorator_args, decorator_kwargs)

            # Execute the original function with its args
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)

            # Do more things after executing the function

            return result

        return wrapper

    # TODO If you need only @my_decorator() or @my_decorator(...) use the else branch only
    # TODO To mitigate TypeError on single callable positional argument allow only keyword arguments:
    #  def my_decorator(func=None, *, decorator_kwarg1='value1', decorator_kwarg2='value2'):  # No **kwargs possible!
    #  and below: if func is not None: _decorator(func) else: _decorator
    # To allow @my_decorator (i.e. without parentheses) WARNING: Use keyword argument for single callable parameter!
    if len(args_or_func) == 1 and len(decorator_kwargs) == 0 and callable(args_or_func[0]):
        # Here you can set default values for positional arguments
        decorator_args = ()
        return _decorator(args_or_func[0])
    else:
        decorator_args = args_or_func  # This "global" variable is used inside _decorator() which is defined above
        return _decorator              # Hint: The function's implementation is evaluated when the function executed


@my_decorator
def func_1(arg): print(arg)


func_1("test1")
# Available inside the wrapper: () {}
# test1


@my_decorator()
def func_2(arg): print(arg)


func_2("test2")
# Available inside the wrapper: () {}
# test2


# Single callable positional argument. BAD INVOCATION! -> TypeError
@my_decorator(lambda x: 42)
def func_3(arg): print(arg)


try:
    func_3("Single callable positional argument. BAD INVOCATION! -> TypeError")
except TypeError as e:
    print("test3")
    print(f"Catched TypeError: TypeError: {e}")
# test3
# Catched TypeError: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable


@my_decorator(lambda x: 42, "any arg")
def func_4(arg): print(arg)


func_4("test4")
# Available inside the wrapper: (<function <lambda> at 0x7f96d94ed870>, 'any arg') {}
# test4


@my_decorator(lambda x: 42, kw="any arg")
def func_5(arg): print(arg)


func_5("test5")
# Available inside the wrapper: (<function <lambda> at 0x7f2dbae3d870>,) {'kw': 'any arg'}
# test5


@my_decorator("arg_1", 2, [3, 4, 5], kwarg_1=1, kwarg_2="2")
def func_6(arg): print(arg)


func_6("test6")
# Available inside the wrapper: ('arg_1', 2, [3, 4, 5]) {'kwarg_1': 1, 'kwarg_2': '2'}
# test6


@my_decorator
@my_decorator()
@my_decorator("stacked")
@my_decorator("arg_1", 2, [3, 4, 5], kwarg_1=1, kwarg_2="2")
def func_7(arg): print(arg)


func_7("test7")
# Available inside the wrapper: () {}
# Available inside the wrapper: () {}
# Available inside the wrapper: ('stacked',) {}
# Available inside the wrapper: ('arg_1', 2, [3, 4, 5]) {'kwarg_1': 1, 'kwarg_2': '2'}
# test7
```

Answer (score -1):

In case both the function and the decorator have to take arguments you can follow the below approach.

For example there is a decorator named `decorator1` which takes an argument

```
@decorator1(5)
def func1(arg1, arg2):
    print (arg1, arg2)

func1(1, 2)
```

Now if the `decorator1` argument has to be dynamic, or passed while calling the function,

```
def func1(arg1, arg2):
    print (arg1, arg2)


a = 1
b = 2
seconds = 10

decorator1(seconds)(func1)(a, b)
```

In the above code

- `seconds` is the argument for `decorator1`
- `a, b` are the arguments of `func1`

Answer (score -1):

Decoration with parameters in an *anonymous* setting.

Among of the many possibilities two variations of a "nested" syntactic sugar decoration are presented. They differ from each other by the order of execution wrt to the target function and their effects are, in general, independent (non interacting).

The decorators allow an "injection" a of custom function either before or after the execution of the target function.

The calls of both functions take place in a `tuple`. As default, the return value is the result of the target function.

The syntactic sugar decoration `@first_internal(send_msg)('...end')` required version >= 3.9, see [PEP 614](https://peps.python.org/pep-0614/) Relaxing Grammar Restrictions On Decorators.

Used `functools.wraps` to keep the doc-string of the target function.

```
from functools import wraps


def first_external(f_external):
    return lambda *args_external, **kwargs_external:\
           lambda f_target: wraps(f_target)(
               lambda *args_target, **kwargs_target:
                  (f_external(*args_external, **kwargs_external),
                   f_target(*args_target, **kwargs_target))[1]
           )


def first_internal(f_external):
    return lambda *args_external, **kwargs_external:\
           lambda f_target: wraps(f_target)(
               lambda *args_target, **kwargs_target:
                  (f_target(*args_target, **kwargs_target),
                   f_external(*args_external, **kwargs_external))[0]
           )


def send_msg(x):
   print('msg>', x)


@first_internal(send_msg)('...end')    # python >= 3.9
@first_external(send_msg)("start...")  # python >= 3.9
def test_function(x):
    """Test function"""
    print('from test_function')
    return x


test_function(2)
```

Output

```
msg> start...
from test_function
msg> ...end
```

**Remarks**

- *composition* decorators, such as pull-back and push-forward (maybe in a more Computer Science terminology: co- and resp. contra-variant decorator), could more useful but need ad-hoc care, for example composition rules, check which parameters go where, etc
- *syntactic sugar* acts as a kind of `partial` of the target function: once decorated there is no way back (without extra imports) but it is not mandatory, a decorator can be used also in its *extended* form*s*, i.e. `first_external(send_msg)("start...")(test_function)(2)`
- the results of a workbench with `timeit.repeat(..., repeat=5, number=10000)` which compare the classical `def` and `lambda` decoration shows that are almost equivalent:

  - for `lambda`: `[6.200810984999862, 6.035239247000391, 5.346362481000142, 5.987880147000396, 5.5331550319997405]` - mean -> `5.8206`
  - for `def`: `[6.165001932999985, 5.554595884999799, 5.798066574999666, 5.678178028000275, 5.446507932999793]` - mean ->  `5.7284`
- naturally an non-anonymous counterpart is possible and provides more flexibility

Comment: Showing that functions can be rewritten as lambdas doesn't really add anything interesting to the solution; it's incidental to the important techniques needed for making the decorator accept parameters.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel No one mentioned a `lambda` approach and I found it curious. Further, I showed that _syntactic sugar_ supports multiple calls and that one can gather abstraction by letting a parameter be a function again

Comment: Because "a lambda approach" is *fundamentally not a different approach*.