# Python decorator get or set dictionary value in class

Tags: python, caching, python-decorators

I'm working on a class representing on object with numerous associated data. I'm storing these data in a dictionary class attribute called *metadata*. A representation could be:

```
{'key1':slowToComputeValue, 'key2':evenSlowerToComputeValue}
```

The calculating of the values is in some cases **very** slow, so what I want to do is, using "getter" functions, first try and get the value from the *metadata*  dict. Only on a KeyError (i.e. when the getter tries to get a value for a key which doesn't exist yet) should the value be calculated (and added to the dictionary for fast access next time the getter is called).

I began with a simple:

```
try:
    return self.metadata[requested_key]
except KeyError:
    #Implementation of function
```

As there are many getters in the class, I started thought that these first 3 lines of code could be handled by a decorator. However I'm having problems making this work. The problem is that I need to pass the metadata dictionary from the class instance to the decorator. I've found several tutorials and posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176226/how-to-pass-extra-arguments-to-python-decorator) one which show that it is possible to send a parameter to an enclosing function but the difficulty I'm having is sending a class instantiation attribute metadata to it (if I send a string value it works).

Some example code from my attempt is here:

```
def get_existing_value_from_metadata_if_exists(metadata):
    def decorator(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            function_name = function.__name__
            if function_name in metadata.keys():
                return metadata[function_name]
            else:
                function(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
    return decorator

class my_class():
    @get_existing_value_from_metadata_if_exists(metadata)
    def get_key1(self):
        #Costly value calculation and add to metadata

    @get_existing_value_from_metadata_if_exists(metadata)
    def get_key2(self):
        #Costly value calculation and add to metadata

    def __init__(self):
        self.metadata = {}
```

The errors I'm getting are generally self not defined but I've tried various combinations of parameter placement, decorator placement etc. without success.

So my questions are:

1. How can I make this work?
2. Are decorators a suitable way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Do you want the data to persist even between different instances of `my_class`?

Comment: No - each instance is related to an audio file. So each instance would have its own set of attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a decorator is a good use case for this. Django for example has something similar already included with it, it's called [`cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property).

Basically all it does is that when the property is accessed first time it will store the data in instance's dict(`__dict__`) by the same name as the function. When we fetch the same property later on it simple fetches the value from the instance dictionary.

A `cached_property` is a [non-data descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol). Hence once the key is set in instance's dictionary, the access to property would always get the value from there.

```
class cached_property(object):
    """
    Decorator that converts a method with a single self argument into a
    property cached on the instance.

    Optional ``name`` argument allows you to make cached properties of other
    methods. (e.g.  url = cached_property(get_absolute_url, name='url') )
    """
    def __init__(self, func, name=None):
        self.func = func
        self.__doc__ = getattr(func, '__doc__')
        self.name = name or func.__name__

    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
        return res
```

In your case:

```
class MyClass:
    @cached_property
    def key1(self):
        #Costly value calculation and add to metadata

    @cached_property
    def key2(self):
        #Costly value calculation and add to metadata

    def __init__(self):
        # self.metadata not required
```

---

Use the `name` argument to convert an existing method to cached property.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def get_total(self):
        print('Processing...')
        return sum(self.data)

    total = cached_property(get_total, 'total')
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> m = MyClass(list(range(10**5)))

>>> m.get_total()
Processing...
4999950000

>>> m.total
Processing...
4999950000

>>> m.total
4999950000

>>> m.data.append(1000)

>>> m.total  # This is now invalid
4999950000

>>> m.get_total()  # This still works
Processing...
4999951000

>>> m.total
4999950000
```

Based on the example above we can see that we can use `total` as long as we know the internal data hasn't been updated yet, hence saving processing time. But it doesn't make `get_total()` redundant, as it can get the correct total based on the data.

Another example could be that our public facing client was using something(say `get_full_name()`) as method so far but we realised that it would be more appropriate to use it as a property(just `full_name`), in that case it makes sense to keep the method intact but mark it as deprecated and start suggesting the users to use the new property from now on.

Comment: Wow what kind of magic is this... It works but I'm still trying to get my head around it. Could you add an example of using the name kwarg?

Comment: @user3535074 What do you mean by "name kwarg"?

Comment: The 'name=None' part of -> def __init__(self, func, name=None)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about this is to use class "properties" like so:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__():
        self._slowToComputeValue = None
    @property
    def slowToComputeValue(self):
        if self._slowToComputeValue is None:
            self._slowToComputeValue = self.ComputeValue()
        return self._slowToComputeValue
    def ComputeValue(self):
        pass
```

Now you can access this as though it were a class attribute:

```
myclass = MyClass()
print(myclass.slowToComputeValue)
```