# How to create a decorator function with arguments on python class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator

I want to create a decorator function to operate on a python class, with the ability to pass additional arguments. I want to do that *before* the class gets instantiated. Here is my approach:

```
def register(x,a):
    print x,a

@register(5)
class Foo(object):
    pass
```

with `x` being the class and `a` the additional argument. But I get a

```
TypeError: register() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

What I want is some way to get hold of the class `Foo` and additional arguments at the time the class is defined, *before* the class is instantiated.

Comment: If you want to do this, you don't define a decorator that accepts two arguments.  You define a function that accepts one argument (your `a`), and make that function return a decorator that accepts one argument (the class).

Comment: But when I define the function with one argument, it is the class! Just remove twice the `,a` above, and the output is `<class '__main__.Foo'>`.

Comment: The solution by @ArtsiomRudzenka worked fine

Comment: possible duplicate of [python decorators with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/python-decorators-with-parameters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do it this way:

```
def makeDeco(a):
    def deco(cls):
        print cls, a
        return cls
    return deco

>>> @makeDeco(3)
... class Foo(object):
...     pass
<class '__main__.Foo'> 3
```

You can use `functools.wraps` and so forth to spruce it up, but that is the idea.  You need to write a function that returns a decorator.  The outer "decorator-making" function takes the `a` argument, and the inner decorator function takes the class.

The way it works is that when you write `@makeDeco(3)` it calls `makeDeco(3)`.  The *return value* of `makeDeco` is what is used as the decorator.  That is why you need `makeDeco` to return the function you want to use as the decorator.

Comment: You would need another nested function to use `@wraps`

Comment: @Bren: I think this is what I need. But one question, though. How does python know that the inner function `deco` is a decorator? Is it just any function inside the outer function?

Comment: @Alex: The return value of the expression after the `@` is what is used as the decorator.  The call `makeDeco(3)` returns a function, so that function is what is used as the decorator.  Note the `return deco` inside `makeDeco`.

Comment: Yes, right, I was somehow misreading to where the second `return` statement belongs to...