# Decorating methods with custom attributes that have properties

Tags: python, django, attributes, decorator, python-decorators

I've got some methods which have attributes (to use .Net terminology). Something like.

```
#Example Usage
@RequireLoggedIn
def SomeAuthorisedFunction():
    # ...
```

The attribute is defined as

```
def RequireLoggedIn(func):
    func.AuthenticationRequired = True
    return func
```

I can then check if this has been set using `hasattr(view_func, 'AuthenticationRequired')`. What I'd like to do is something like this...

```
@RequireRole('Administrator')
def SomeAuthorisedFunction():
    # ...
```

I've tried defining an attribute like this:

```
def RequireRole(func, Role):
    func.RequiresRole = Role
    return func
```

But `@RequireRole('Administrator')` results in `missing positional argument "Role"` and `@RequireRole(Role='Administrator')` results in `missing positional argument "func"`.

How can I specify properties for attributes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/python-decorators-with-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a *nested* function; the `RequireRole` function should return the actual decorator function:

```
def RequireRole(Role):
    def decorator(func):
        func.RequiresRole = Role
        return func
    return decorator
```

The `@expression` syntax is nothing more than syntactic sugar, the following setup:

```
@decorator
def foo(): pass
```

is translated to:

```
def foo(): pass
foo = decorator(foo)
```

instead. But the `decorator` part can *itself* be an expression too; that is how you are trying to use it. So when you use `@RequireRole('Administrator')` as a decorator, you really do this:

```
def SomeAuthorisedFunction():
    # ...
SomeAuthorisedFunction = RequireRole('Administrator')(SomeAuthorisedFunction)
```

Note the *double* function call there! This is why my version of `RequireRole()` returns a nested function. This is what happens when you apply it:

1. `def SomeAuthorizedFunction(): functionbody` is executed.
2. `RequireRole('Administrator') is executed. It returns a scoped`decorator()` function.
3. This returned function is called and passed in the `SomeAuthorizedFunction` function from step 1.
4. The scoped `decorator()` function adds the `.RequiresRole` attribute to the function, with the scoped `Role` value passed into `RequireRole` in step 2. The function is returned.
5. Python assigns the return value of step 4 to the name `SomeAuthorizedFunction`.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick and detailed response

Answer (score 1):

Your `RequireRole` function must return a decorator function. This can easily be
accomplished via a nested function, like so:

```
>>> def RequireRole(role):
...   def RequireRole(func):
...     func.RequiresRole = role
...     return func
...   return RequireRole
... 
>>> @RequireRole('Administrator')
... def SomeAuthorisedFunction():
...   pass
... 
>>> print SomeAuthorisedFunction.RequiresRole
Administrator
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a rapid response