# Using Decorator for Data Driven Tests

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to parametrize a function using decorator. Finally I am able to get it run as expected after lot of hit and trials. But still I am not satisfied as though it is working, it doesn't seem to be right way to do it.

Please help me improve this code.

Here is my code:

```
def WarmWelcome(fn):
    def wrapped(DataProvider):
       for name in DataProvider(): 
         print fn(name) + ":)"
    return wrapped

def DataProvider():
    names=["abc","xyz","def"]
    for name in names:
        yield name

@WarmWelcome
def hello(name):
    return "hello " +name

hello(DataProvider)
```

Here is the updated code:

```
def WarmWelcome(DataProvider):
  def real_decorator(fn):
    def wrapped():
       for name in DataProvider(): 
         print fn(name) + ":)"
    return wrapped
  return real_decorator

def DataProvider():
    names=["abc","xyz","def"]
    for name in names:
        yield name
@WarmWelcome(DataProvider)
def hello(name):
    return "hello " +name

hello()
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: As per my understanding the better way would be to pass the DataProvider through decorator function.Something like this:@WarmWelcome(DataProvider()) but I could not get it run this way.

Comment: @vishul9, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5929165/521590) on how to implement a decorator with arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also possible to provide dataset right to `WarmWelcome` decorator:

```
def WarmWelcome(*data_sets):
    def _decorator(func):
        def _func():
            for ds in data_sets:
                func(*ds)
        return _func
    return _decorator

@WarmWelcome(
    ("abc", ),
    ("xyz", ),
    ("def", ),
)
def hello(name):
    return "hello " +name
```

Original: [PHPUnit-like dataProvider implementation for Python unittest](https://gist.github.com/renskiy/7165930#file-data_provider-py)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: I think you need to put your strings in 1-tuples or do something other than unpacking them as arguments to the wrapped function for this to work. As written, if you call `hello()` you'll get an error from unpacking the string and calling the original function with two many arguments, e.g.: `hello('a', 'b', 'c')`. If you call `hello("Bob")` you get a different error about `_func` not taking any positional arguments. Usually a decorator shouldn't change the call signature of a method!