# How to test Python 3.4 asyncio code?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-asyncio

What's the best way to write unit tests for code using the Python 3.4 `asyncio` library? Assume I want to test a TCP client (`SocketConnection`):

```
import asyncio
import unittest

class TestSocketConnection(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_server = MockServer("localhost", 1337)
        self.socket_connection = SocketConnection("localhost", 1337)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def test_sends_handshake_after_connect(self):
        yield from self.socket_connection.connect()
        self.assertTrue(self.mock_server.received_handshake())
```

When running this test case with the default test runner, the test will always succeed as the method executes only up until the first `yield from` instruction, after which it returns before executing any assertions. This causes tests to always succeed.

Is there a prebuilt test runner that is able to handle asynchronous code like this?

Comment: you could use `loop.run_until_complete()` instead of `yield from`. See also `asyncio.test_utils`.

Comment: For python 3.5+ `async def` and `await` syntax, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263988/test-calling-a-python-coroutine-async-def-from-a-regular-function/

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Since Python 3.8 [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html) comes with the [IsolatedAsyncioTestCase](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html#unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase) function, designed for this purpose.

```python
from unittest import IsolatedAsyncioTestCase

class Test(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):

    async def test_functionality(self):
        result = await functionality()
        self.assertEqual(expected, result)
```

Comment: Too bad this answer is shown after no less than 5 workarounds only as of today.

Comment: @Marvin Killing could accept this answer and that would change maybe...

Comment: Very great answer. This saves my life! Async tests should not be a permanent stop and frustrated issue for py developers.

Answer (score 62):

I temporarily solved the problem using a decorator inspired by Tornado's [gen_test](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html#tornado.testing.gen_test):

```
def async_test(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        coro = asyncio.coroutine(f)
        future = coro(*args, **kwargs)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(future)
    return wrapper
```

Like J.F. Sebastian suggested, this decorator will block until the test method coroutine has finished. This allows me to write test cases like this:

```
class TestSocketConnection(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_server = MockServer("localhost", 1337)
        self.socket_connection = SocketConnection("localhost", 1337)

    @async_test
    def test_sends_handshake_after_connect(self):
        yield from self.socket_connection.connect()
        self.assertTrue(self.mock_server.received_handshake())
```

This solution probably misses some edge cases.

I think a facility like this should added to Python's standard library to make `asyncio` and `unittest` interaction more convenient out of the box.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this solution so the decorator uses a specific loop, not the threads default loop?

Comment: Yes, function annotations can take arguments in Python, so you can pass an event loop there. Note that writing annotations that take arguments is a *liitle* confusing at first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5929165/823869

Comment: @JackO'Connor I think you mean function _decorators_ not function _annotations_ as function _annotations_ has a specific meaning in Python:  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#function-annotations

Comment: I ran into issues with `asyncio.get_event_loop()` and used `asyncio.new_event_loop()`

Comment: Warning that `asyncio.coroutine` is deprecated and will be removed in py3.10: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#generator-based-coroutines

Comment: Also using "get_event_loop" to create or get a loop is deprecated, it will only get the current running loop starting with 3.11

Answer (score 55):

`async_test`, suggested by Marvin Killing, definitely can help -- as well as direct calling `loop.run_until_complete()`

But I also strongly recommend to recreate new event loop for every test and directly pass loop to API calls (at least `asyncio` itself accepts `loop` keyword-only parameter for every call that need it).

Like

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(None)

    def test_xxx(self):
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def go():
            reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection(
                '127.0.0.1', 8888, loop=self.loop)
            yield from asyncio.sleep(0.01, loop=self.loop)
        self.loop.run_until_complete(go())
```

that isolates tests in test case and prevents strange errors like longstanding coroutine that has been created in `test_a` but finished only on `test_b` execution time.

Comment: Is there any reason why you do `asyncio.set_event_loop(None)` and later pass `self.loop` explicitly to `asyncio.open_connection()` instead of just doing `asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)` right from the start?

Comment: Well, it's just my habit. When I working on asyncio and or aio-based libraries I use `asyncio.set_event_loop(None)` to directly specify the fact that the library should not relay on global loop existence and safely work by explicit loop passing.
It's code style for asyncio tests itself, I use it in my libraries too.

Comment: This example should also mock `asyncio.open_connection` shouldn't it? Running it produces `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 8888)`

Comment: @terrycojones mock is not always required. In example I use local address, so I may setup test server on the address before test run or in `setUp` method. Concrete implementation depends on your needs.

Comment: Adds more boilterplate in place but definitively this is the way of make tests unitary and isolated

Comment: and remember to close the loop in tearDown

Answer (score 31):

Really like the `async_test` wrapper mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23036785/350195, here is an updated version for Python 3.5+

```
def async_test(coro):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        try:
            return loop.run_until_complete(coro(*args, **kwargs))
        finally:
            loop.close()
    return wrapper



class TestSocketConnection(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_server = MockServer("localhost", 1337)
        self.socket_connection = SocketConnection("localhost", 1337)

    @async_test
    async def test_sends_handshake_after_connect(self):
        await self.socket_connection.connect()
        self.assertTrue(self.mock_server.received_handshake())
```

Comment: for anyone using `nosetests`, you might want to rename the decorator or nose thinks it's actually a test as well, with a mysterious message about `async_test` missing a required positional argument.  I renamed to `asynctest` and added an additional decorator `@nose.tools.istest` to make the testcase autodiscoverable

Comment: Wrap `async_test` with `nose.tools.nottest` decorator if using `nosetests`.

Comment: this is beautiful. Incorporating in my project. Thank you!

Comment: In my Odoo installation, even though I'm using Python 3.10, the top answer to use `IsolatedAsyncioTestCase` is not working, but this is; thanks!

Answer (score 19):

[pytest-asyncio](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio) looks promising:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_some_asyncio_code():
    res = await library.do_something()
    assert b'expected result' == res
```

Comment: There is an issue with the pytest approach when using `unittest.TestCase`, that make very limited for me. http://jacobbridges.github.io/post/unit-testing-with-asyncio/

Comment: Looks like an issue was filed with them here.  No solution yet.
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/issues/15

Comment: Also mocking classes via mock.patch stops working. https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/issues/42

Answer (score 12):

You can also use [`aiounittest`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aiounittest) that takes similar approach as @Andrew Svetlov, @Marvin Killing answers and wrap it in easy to use `AsyncTestCase` class:

```
import asyncio
import aiounittest


async def add(x, y):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    return x + y

class MyTest(aiounittest.AsyncTestCase):

    async def test_async_add(self):
        ret = await add(5, 6)
        self.assertEqual(ret, 11)

    # or 3.4 way
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def test_sleep(self):
        ret = yield from add(5, 6)
        self.assertEqual(ret, 11)

    # some regular test code
    def test_something(self):
        self.assertTrue(true)
```

As you can see the async case is handled by `AsyncTestCase`. It supports also synchronous test. There is a possibility to provide custom event loop, just override `AsyncTestCase.get_event_loop`.

If you prefer (for some reason) the other TestCase class (eg `unittest.TestCase`), you might use `async_test` decorator:

```
import asyncio
import unittest
from aiounittest import async_test


async def add(x, y):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    return x + y

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @async_test
    async def test_async_add(self):
        ret = await add(5, 6)
        self.assertEqual(ret, 11)
```

Answer (score 11):

Use this class instead of `unittest.TestCase` base class:

```
import asyncio
import unittest


class AioTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    # noinspection PyPep8Naming
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest', loop=None):
        self.loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._function_cache = {}
        super(AioTestCase, self).__init__(methodName=methodName)

    def coroutine_function_decorator(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            return self.loop.run_until_complete(func(*args, **kw))
        return wrapper

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, item)
        if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(attr):
            if item not in self._function_cache:
                self._function_cache[item] = self.coroutine_function_decorator(attr)
            return self._function_cache[item]
        return attr


class TestMyCase(AioTestCase):

    async def test_dispatch(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```

**EDIT 1:**

Please note the @Nitay [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60986764/680372) about nested tests.

Comment: This is a great solution. Added in a slight change here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60986764/328059

Comment: Please add a description to your code. Code only is not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I usually define my async tests as coroutines and use a decorator for "syncing" them:

```
import asyncio
import unittest

def sync(coro):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(coro(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper

class TestSocketConnection(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_server = MockServer("localhost", 1337)
        self.socket_connection = SocketConnection("localhost", 1337)

    @sync
    async def test_sends_handshake_after_connect(self):
        await self.socket_connection.connect()
        self.assertTrue(self.mock_server.received_handshake())
```

Answer (score 2):

pylover answer is correct and is something that should be added to unittest IMO.

I would add in a slight change to support nested async tests:

```py
class TestCaseBase(unittest.TestCase):
    # noinspection PyPep8Naming
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest', loop=None):
        self.loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._function_cache = {}
        super(BasicRequests, self).__init__(methodName=methodName)

    def coroutine_function_decorator(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            # Is the io loop is already running? (i.e. nested async tests)
            if self.loop.is_running():
                t = func(*args, **kw)
            else:
                # Nope, we are the first
                t = self.loop.run_until_complete(func(*args, **kw))
            return t

        return wrapper

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, item)
        if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(attr):
            if item not in self._function_cache:
                self._function_cache[item] = self.coroutine_function_decorator(attr)
            return self._function_cache[item]
        return attr
```

Answer (score 2):

I found python test file have a similar 'async_test' function like Marvin Killing's answer. Because "@coroutine" decorator is deprecated since Python 3.8. When I use python3.8 or above. I got a "DeprecationWarning".

If you use Python 3.5+. This answer maybe a good option. Hope helps.

```
import asyncio
import functools


def async_test(func):
    """Decorator to turn an async function into a test case."""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        coro = func(*args, **kwargs)
        asyncio.run(coro)
    return wrapper
```

Test example:

```
import unittest


async def add_func(a, b):
    return a + b


class TestSomeCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @async_test
    async def test_add_func(self):
        self.assertEqual(await add_func(1, 2), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to pylover's answer, if you intend to use some other asynchronous method from the test class itself, the following implementation will work better -

```
import asyncio
import unittest

class AioTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    # noinspection PyPep8Naming
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest', loop=None):
        self.loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._function_cache = {}
        super(AioTestCase, self).__init__(methodName=methodName)

    def coroutine_function_decorator(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            return self.loop.run_until_complete(func(*args, **kw))
        return wrapper

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, item)
        if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(attr) and item.startswith('test_'):
            if item not in self._function_cache:
                self._function_cache[item] = 
                    self.coroutine_function_decorator(attr)
            return self._function_cache[item]
        return attr


class TestMyCase(AioTestCase):

    async def multiplier(self, n):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # just to show the difference
        return n*2

    async def test_dispatch(self):
        m = await self.multiplier(2)
        self.assertEqual(m, 4)
```

the only change was - `and item.startswith('test_')` in the `__getattribute__` method.