# Testing asyncio-based services

Tags: testing, python-asyncio

I'm implementing small service using asyncio using a loop that is structured as follows:

```
pending = {...}
while True:
  done, pending = yield from asyncio.wait( 
    pending, 
    return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED, 
  )
  for future in done:
    if future is x:
      # ...
    if future is y:
      # ...
```

This loop is currently controlling a sub-process, but having written a bunch of ZMQ-based services, this style feels very natural, so I'll likely be writing more of these in the near future.

I have something that runs just the way I like, but I'm kind of at a loss as to how I would write automated tests for this.

I would *like* to have my tests start this loop until it blocks on `asyncio.wait()` and inject one particular event to test the loop's handling of that particular event.  That way, I can test each possible event handling and know I cover all cases as expected.

However, I can't find anything in `asyncio` that provides for this.  If I simply `yield from` this coroutine, the test does not unblock until the coroutine completes.

Any ideas on how to test this particular kind of loop?

---

**Edit**: OK, so I managed to get something running using a `socketpair()` by patching `sys.stdout` with the write end and wrapping the other end in a `StreamReader`.

This works when I run pytest without capture, but as soon as remove the `-s` argument, the test seems to deadlock.

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033939/how-to-test-python-3-4-asyncio-code/

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov Thanks, but none of the answers there are helpful.  Currently, this code is running a sub-process and does not have a network interface, so my test cannot simply have another coroutine that exchanges messages with the coroutine to be tested.  I also cannot use `.run_until_complete()` because I want to test intermediate states...