# Test calling a python coroutine (async def) from a regular function

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5, python-asyncio

Let's say I have some asyncio coroutine which fetches some data and returns it. Like this:

```
async def fetch_data(*args):
  result = await some_io()
  return result
```

Basically this coroutine is called from the chain of coroutines, and initial coroutine is runned by creating a task.
But what if for test purposes I want to run only one coroutine this way just when running some file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  result = await fetch_data(*args)
  print(result)
```

And obviously I can't do this since I'm trying to run and await coroutine from not coroutine function.
So the question is: is there some correct way to get data from coroutine without calling it function?
I can make some `Future` object for `result` and await it, but maybe there are some other more simple and clearer ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an event loop to run your coroutine:

```
import asyncio

async def async_func():
    return "hello"

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
result = loop.run_until_complete(async_func())
loop.close()

print(result)
```

Or as a function:

```
def run_coroutine(f, *args, **kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(f(*args, **kwargs))
    loop.close()
    return result
```

Use like this:

```
print(run_coroutine(async_func))
```

Or:

```
assert "expected" == run_coroutine(fetch_data, "param1", param2="foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.7+, you may use `asyncio.run()`:

```py
import asyncio

async def fetch_data():
  return "sample_data"

asyncio.run(fetch_data())
```