# Python 3.6: How to write unit tests properly?

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, python-3.6

I'm a new with Python 3.6 (was writing a code on Python 2.X a few years) and I'm trying to write some unit tests for my asynchronous code.

I have some asynchronous function like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    async def my_func(self):
        # Doing something with 'await', etc.
```

Also, I'm writing my test like this:

```
class MyClassTest(unittest.TestCase):
    async def test_my_func(self):
        my_class_instance = MyClass()
        data = await my_class_instance.my_func()
```

I hope, this should work, but running this test like this:

```
notetests -s my_tests.py
```

Shows me an issue:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py:605: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MyClassTest.my_func' was never awaited testMethod()
```

It looks like I have `await` and it should work fine, but my `data` is not containing any data.

What went wrong?

P.S. I'm not using tornado, that's why there is no sense to add this dependency here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test Python 3.4 asyncio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033939/how-to-test-python-3-4-asyncio-code)

Comment: @LexScarisbrick, I was reading a few similar topics, but it looks like this requires to write some custom decorators, etc. It looks strange for me because I think that some default behavior should exist.

Comment: Async code needs to run in an event loop; that applies to tests, as well. The custom decorators in the answer @LexScarisbrick mentioned sets that up for you.

Comment: that is not a solution for `nosetests`, as it doesnt discover the tests.