# Testing aiohttp client with unittest.mock.patch

Tags: python, testing, patch, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I've written a simple HTTP client using aiohttp and I'm trying to test it by patching `aiohttp.ClientSession` and `aiohttp.ClientResponse`. However, it appears as though the `unittest.mock.patch` decorator is not respecting my asynchronous code. At a guess, I would say it's some kind of namespacing mismatch.

Here's a minimal example:

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def is_ok(url:str) -> bool:
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.request("GET", url) as response:
            return (response.status == 200)
```

I'm using an asynchronous decorator for testing, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23036785/876937). So here's my attempted test:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from aiohttp import ClientResponse

from my.original.module import is_ok

class TestClient(unittest.TestCase):
    @async_test
    @patch("my.original.module.ClientSession", spec=True)
    async def test_client(self, mock_client):
        mock_response = MagicMock(spec=ClientResponse)
        mock_response.status = 200

        async def _mock_request(*args, **kwargs):
            return mock_response

        mock_client.request = mock_response

        status = await is_ok("foo")
        self.assertTrue(status)
```

My `is_ok` coroutine works fine when it's used in, say, `__main__`, but when I run the test, it gives me an error that indicates that the `session.request` function has not been mocked per my `patch` call. (Specifically it says "Could not parse hostname from URL 'foo'", which it should if it *weren't* mocked.)

I am unable to escape this behaviour. I have tried:

- Importing `is_ok` after the mocking is done.
- Various combinations of assigning mocks to `mock_client` and `mock_client.__aenter__`, setting `mock_client.request` to `MagicMock(return_value=mock_response)`, or using `mock_client().request`, etc.
- Writing a mock `ClientSession` with specific `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` methods and using it in the `new` argument to `patch`.

None of these appear to make a difference. If I put assertions into `is_ok` to test that `ClientSession` is an instance of `MagicMock`, then these assertions fail when I run the test (as, again, they would when the code is not patched). That leads me to my namespacing mismatch theory: That is, the event loop is running in a different namespace to which `patch` is targeting.

Either that, or I'm doing something stupid!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Mocking `ClientSession` is discouraged.

Recommended way is creation fake server and sending *real* requests to it.

Take a look on [aiohttp example](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/examples/fake_server.py).

Comment: It's like a test database usage instead of mocking all SQL executions.

Comment: Yeah, a la integration testing. Understandable and necessary, but arguably overkill if you just wanna test control flow.

Comment: You could take a look on https://github.com/pnuckowski/aioresponses though.

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks

Comment: I don't think that is the answer for the question

Comment: You are free to disagree, sure. As aiohttp library author I'm just sharing my vision about proper library usage.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov  aioresponses seems mock all of the requests. will cause others places' get or post failed

Comment: Yes, this is my concern too

Comment: I understand, that for testing `ClientSession` it is best to use a fake server.
However for testing code, that just uses `ClientSession` it would still be great to have a solution that runs without a fake server.

Pity, that `aioresponses` seems to be more monkeypatching than mocking and could thus have weird side effects.

Perhaps a mix of mock-patching `ClientSession` with a subclass and monkeypatching the subclass would work?