# Testing a function wrapper that returns a coroutine

Tags: python-asyncio

I have a function similar to the following:

```
def wrapper(fn, client):
    async def helper(*args, **kwargs):
        id_ = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
            status = client.get_status(id_)
            if status == 'OK':
                break
        return status
    return helper
```

Basically it takes a function, which launches a compute job somewhere. The coroutine then asks the status of this compute job every 60 seconds and if the status is OK then it breaks from the infinite loop.

To test it I am using:

```
classs Test_wrapper(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_wrapper(self):
        client = get_client()
        aio_fn = wraper(fn, client)
        coro = aio_fn(arg1, arg2, arg3=arg3, arg4=arg4)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(coro)
        loop.close()
```

I have also tested variations of the alternatives shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033939/how-to-test-python-3-4-asyncio-code) by I do not get it to work. I have run the wraper outside pytest and it works.

I have tested this `wrapper` running the code it is suppose to run, but the tests keep failing. Do you have any clue?

No error message or exeption is displayed when it fails, it only says that it fails.

Comment: How is it failing? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Note that your wrapper is not a decorator in the Python sense of the word (function usable with `@xxx` syntax). A decorator must either take a single argument, the function, or it must take multiple arguments, and return a decorator that takes a single argument.

Comment: @dirn no error message or exception is shown it only says that 1 test failed and I know is this one because nothing fails if I comment this out. @user4815162342 I suggest you read [this](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) and see why this `wrapper` is also called a decorator in python. Anyway I updated the title so that others do not get confused, please help if you have a clue

Comment: I'm well aware of what decorator means in Python. If you actually read through the document you linked to, you'll see that your wrapper function is *not* a decorator because it is not usable with the `@decorator` syntax.

Comment: @user4815162342 it would be nice if you try to help me with my question, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: py.test normally prints some error when the test; have you tried `--pdb`?