# test a function that must be called via invoking a delegate

Tags: python, function, unit-testing, asynchronous, python-unittest

I have a class named `Tower`:

```py
class Tower:
    def __init__(self, # params..):
        # some settings of variables 
        add_game_turn_event(self._update)
    def turn_result(self):
        # some action
```

as you can see, `turn_result` is subscribed to a collection of methods which invokes every x seconds:

```
game_turn_events = []

def add_game_turn_event(function):
    game_turn_events.append(function)

async def _game_turn():
    while True:
        threading.Timer(sec_per_turn, _game_turn).start()
        for function in game_turn_events:
            function()
```

now I want to write a unit test (using the `unittest`  module) that creates a tower, and then checks how the tower has changed after `turn_result` is invoked once. I don't really know how to do it. I though about something like:

```py
def test_tower_updating(self):
    tower = Tower( # params..)
    add_game_turn_event(lambda: self._test_tower_updating(tower, 10 + levels[2].yield_per_turn))

def _test_tower_updating(self, tower, expected):
    self.assertTrue(tower.warriors_group.soldiers_amount == expected)
```

but this does not wait for the function to be invoked and gives false positive anyways. the problem is, that `_game_turn()` is async, so it dosen't wait for it to finish. `await` won't work here, because I dont call  `_game_turn()` directly, rather I update a global variable it uses.

How can I test such thing?

Comment: Have a look at [how to test python 3.4 asyncio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033939/how-to-test-python-3-4-asyncio-code) - there are some answers that may help you.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen as I said, asinco is called indirectly so it won't work