# Passing arguments to a decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I want to pass a list of values to a decorator. Every function which is decorated by the decorator passes different list of values. I am using the `decorator` python library

Here is what I was trying -

```
from decorator import decorator
def dec(func, *args):
     // Do something with the *args - I guess *args contains the arguments
     return func()

dec = decorator(dec)

@dec(['first_name', 'last_name'])
def my_function_1():
    // Do whatever needs to be done

@dec(['email', 'zip'])
def my_function_2():
    // Do whatever needs to be done
```

However, this does not work. It gives an error - `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'func_globals'`

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/python-decorators-with-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it without decorator library

```
def custom_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
    # process decorator params
    def wrapper(func):
        def dec(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return dec
    return wrapper

@custom_decorator(['first_name', 'last_name'])
def my_function_1():
    pass
@custom_decorator(['email', 'zip'])
def my_function_2():
    pass
```

Comment: That's cool. Anyway this could be implemented with the `decorator` library though?