# How does python determine the decorator parameter mapping?

Tags: python, python-3.x

(This is a newbie Python question)

As I tried the Python `decorator` with code below, I am a bit puzzled how Python map the `Test` method name to the parameters at different levels. How does Python know the `Test` method should be map to `name2`? Is it because `name1` has already been provided with `"tom"`? But it seems to be a naive reason.

I know the `@decorator` is just a syntax sugar. What's going on behined the scene?

```
def level1(name1):
    print("in level1 with %s" % name1)
    def level2(name2):
        print("in level2 with %s..." % name2)
        def level3():
            return "nonthing is done..."
        return level3        
    return level2



@level1("tom")
def Test():
    print("MyClass.Test is callled")
    return "I am Result"

if(__name__ =="__main__"):
    print("Result is: %s" % Test())
```

The output is:

```
in level1 with tom
in level2 with <function Test at 0x0000000001DD33C8>...
Result is: nonthing is done...
```

Answer (score 2):

By writing `@level1("tom")`, you call the function `@level1` with argument `"tom"`.  This assigns `"tom"` to the argument of `level1`, namely `name1`.  This is just the same as what would happen if you didn't use it as a decorator and just called `level1("tom")`.

Since you used the expression `level1("tom")` as a decorator, the result of this expression --- that is, the return value of the call to `level1` --- is itself called with the decorated function (`Test`) as its argument.  In this type of construct, `level1` is not really a decorator.  Rather, it is a decorator-maker, or decorator factory.  The return value of level1 is what actually decorates `Test`. In this case the return value of `level1` is the function `level2`.  Remember that using decorator like this:

```
@deco
def fun():
    # blah
```

is the same as this:

```
def fun():
    # blah
fun = deco(fun)
```

In your case, the decorator is the return value of `level1`, namely `level2`.  That means that your code is equivalent to:

```
deco = level1("tom")
def Test():
    print("MyClass.Test is callled")
    return "I am Result"
Test = deco(Test)
```

`deco` is thus `level2`, since that is what `level1` returns.  Since `Test` is what is passed to `level2`, it is assigned to the argument of `level2`, which is `name2`.

You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/python-decorators-with-parameters) on the same topic to be helpful as well.

Comment: Technically, I guess the `decorator-maker chain` could be of any depth. And Python just keeps calling the method until it finds a method without an argument passed in by programmer. Then Python will pass in the decorated method as the argument.

Comment: @smwikipedia: Not sure what you mean.  Do you mean that you cannot do `@nested_maker()()()`?  The decorator expression cannot be a full expression but is limited to a series of attribute references (i.e., a dotted name) optionally followed by a single argument list.  So you can have `one.two.three('blah')` but not `one['two']('blah')` or `one('two')('three')`.