# Python decorators calling functions in different classes

Tags: python, function, arguments, decorator

I am attempting to write a decorator which calls on two additional functions and runs them in addition to the function it is decorating in a specific order.

I have tried something along these lines:

```
class common(): 
    def decorator(setup, teardown, test):
        def wrapper(self):
            setup
            test
            teardown
        return wrapper

class run():
    def setup(self):
        print("in setup")

    def teardown(self):
        print("in teardown")

    @common.decorator(setup, teardown)
    def test(self):
        print("in test")
```

The final goal would be to have the decorator make the test run with the following flow setup > test  > teardown. I know I am not calling on the setup and teardown correctly however. I would appreciate any help in how I should do this, I am new in using python and my knowledge of decorators involving arguments is limited.

Comment: What point would there to be for the decorator to be a method on a class? You don't seem to be using the context of the class.

Comment: For decorators with parameters see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5929107/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorators on methods are applied when the class is being defined, which means that the `setup` and `teardown` methods are not bound at that time. This just means you need to pass in the `self` argument manually.

You'll also need to create an outer decorator factory; something that returns the actual decorator, based on your arguments:

```
def decorator(setup, teardown):
    def decorate_function(test):
        def wrapper(self):
            setup(self)
            test(self)
            teardown(self)
        return wrapper
    return decorate_function
```

Demo:

```
>>> def decorator(setup, teardown):
...     def decorate_function(test):
...         def wrapper(self):
...             setup(self)
...             test(self)
...             teardown(self)
...         return wrapper
...     return decorate_function
... 
>>> class run():
...     def setup(self):
...         print("in setup")
...     def teardown(self):
...         print("in teardown")
...     @decorator(setup, teardown)
...     def test(self):
...         print("in test")
... 
>>> run().test()
in setup
in test
in teardown
```