# Function decorators with parameters on a class based view in Django

Tags: django, python-decorators

The official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) explains how to decorate a class based view, however I could not find any information on how to provide **parameters** to the decorator.

I would like to achieve something like

```
class MyView(View):
    @method_decorator(mydecorator, some_parameters)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

which should be equivalent to

```
@mydecorator(some_parameters)
def my_view(request):
    ....
```

How do I deal with such cases?

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/python-decorators-with-parameters help?

Comment: Not really because it does not cover class based views.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`@method_decorator` takes a function as parameter. If you want to pass a decorator with parameters, you only need to:

- Evaluate the parameters in the decorator-creator function.
- Pass the evaluated value to `@method_decorator`.

In explicit Python code this would be:

```
decorator = mydecorator(arg1, arg2, arg...)
method_dec = method_decorator(decorator)

class MyClass(View):
    @method_dec
    def my_view(request):
        ...
```

So, using the syntactic sugar completely:

```
class MyClass(View):
    @method_decorator(mydecorator(arg1, arg2, arg...))
    def my_view(request):
        ...
```