# Python decorator TypeError 'object is not callable'

Tags: python, decorator, python-2.x

I am trying to get myself familiar with decorators.
This is a program I created to do so, but it keeps giving me an `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` error, which I don't know how to fix.

```
#Filename: decorator_practice.py

def add(x):
    def add_1():
        add_1 = x() + 1
    return add_1

def minus(x):
    def minus_1():
        return x() - 1
    return minus_1

def multi(x, times=2):
    def multi_2():
        return x() * 2
    def multi_3():
        return x() * 3
    def multi_4():
        return x() * 4

    if times == 2:
        return multi_2
    elif times == 3:
        return multi_3
    elif times == 4:
        return multi_4
    else:
        return "Please enter times between 2 and 4"

def create_x():
    x = input('Give variable x a value: ')
    return x

add(create_x()())
```

I run this and type: `5`

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: but why not? create_x returns x which lets say is 5!
in the function add(x) will give me ---> return 5 + 1! Why not then? :/

Comment: Because it does not give you `5+1`, it gives you `5()() + 1`, trying to call the `5` as if it were a function. This is what the error message refers to. (And if calling `5` were successful, your program would try to call the result again. The first call comes from the second set of parens in your `create_x()()`, the second call comes from the `x()` in `add_1`.)

Comment: Dear readers from the future: Please note the above is **Python 2**. In Python 3, `input()` will simply return the input, in Python 2, it will evaluate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `create_x` function *returns an integer*:

```
def create_x():
    x = input('Give variable x a value: ')
    return x
```

so `create_x()()` is *never going to work*.

Part of the problem is that you've used poor parameter names, which is confusing you - you have two `x`s which refer to two *completely different things*. Using your `add` decorator as an example, modify to:

```
def add(func):
    def add_1():
        return func() + 1  # you should return from the inner function
    return add_1
```

Now hopefully it is clear that the argument to `add` should be a function, which is called inside `add_1`. Therefore you could do:

```
adder = add(create_x)  # don't call create_x yet!
adder()  # calling add_1, which calls create_x
```

which simplifies to:

```
add(create_x)()  # note ordering of parentheses
```

Note that this could also be written:

```
@add
def create_x():
    ...

create_x()
```

where the syntax `@add` means `create_x = add(create_x)`.

---

Once you've mastered simple decorators, note that your `multi` will not work as you expect - see e.g. [python decorators with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5929107/3001761) for creating decorators that take arguments.

Comment: Thank you!!! However, shouldn't add(create_x()) work? I mean instead of add(create_x()())???
why does adder() works? isn't adder() == add(create_x()() ??

Comment: @midkin No, as I've just edited in it's `add(create_x)()` - the order of parentheses is important, you need to *pass a **function** to `add`*, and then *call the result*. Your attempt `add(create_x())` will *pass an integer to `add`*, which then cannot be called inside `add_1`.

Comment: UPDATE: Wait!!! add(create_x)() doesn't do what i want! It doe NOT return anything!!! It should return 6! Please try it!

Comment: @midkin Have you included my modifications to `add`? You need to `return` from `add_1`. I *have* tested the code I posted, and it works fine here.

Comment: Sorry you are right!!! So my MAIN PROBLEM was that I wasn't RETURNING in add_1, right?

Comment: @midkin no, your code wasn't getting that far; the issue causing your error was that you were passing an integer, not a function, to `add`.

Comment: IF... If i had the return there it would work... Cause before trying the add(create_x)()() thing I DID try add(create_x)() :/

Comment: pffff! Now I see! instead of add(create_x)() or add(create_x)()() I was writting add(create_x()) and add(create_x()())! Tragic man!!!

Answer (score 3):

You have unnecessary `()`, change `add(create_x()())` to `add(create_x())`,
and I suggest using `x = int(raw_input('Give variable x a value: '))`

See the following example:

```
def add(x):
    def add_1():
        #add_1 = x() + 1 # remove this line 
        return x+1
    return add_1

def create_x():
    x = input('Give variable x a value: ')
    return x

b = add(create_x())
print 'answer: ', b()

localhost# python t.py 
Give variable x a value: 5
answer: 6
```

Comment: I 've tried it! That's not the solution:
<function add_1 at 0x0000000002A5BA58>

Comment: The same problem is still there!

Comment: add(create_x()()) is the right one for sure and not add(create_x())! Try it!

Comment: @midkin Sorry for confusion, see my updated example.

Comment: @PaulLo that is no longer really a decorator

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah...your answer make more sense