# How to Override a Python class's __str__ method on construction with argument?

Tags: python

I can do this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName

    def __str__(self):
        print self.firstName

bob = Person('Robert', 'Smith')
print bob
>>> Robert
```

But I want to do it more generically rather than overriding `__str__` for every class manually.  I've tried using decorators and metaclasses, but I am confounded.  I think that it should be possible to do something similar to this, but I don't know how to make the decorator or metaclass accept an argument and still create a properly instantiable object:

```
class strAs:

    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop

    def __call__(self, cls):
        decoratorSelf = self
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            def __str__(s):
                return getattr(s, decoratorSelf.prop)

            c = cls(*args, **kwargs)
            c.__str__ = __str__

            return c
        return wrapper


@strAs(prop='firstName')
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName

@strAs(prop='name')
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

bob = Person('Robert', 'Smith')
fido = Dog('Fido')

print bob
print fido

>>> Robert
Fido
```

But this fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/py6495xVN", line 33, in <module>
    print bob
TypeError: __str__() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I can't figure out why `__str__()` is not getting `self` passed to it.  I noticed that the `bob` instance of the `Person` class seems to be missing some typical object methods, so I tried I subclassing `object` like this (and added two print statements):

```
class strAs(object):

    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop

    def __call__(self, cls):
        decoratorSelf = self
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print 'in wrapper'
            def __newstr__(s):
                print 'in newstr'
                return getattr(s, decoratorSelf.prop)

            c = cls(*args, **kwargs)
            c.__str__ = __newstr__

            return c
        return wrapper


@strAs(prop='firstName')
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName

@strAs(prop='name')
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

bob = Person('Robert', 'Smith')
fido = Dog('Fido')

print bob
print fido
```

And now I get some output with `__str__` apparently being called correctly:

```
>>> in wrapper
in wrapper
<__main__.Person object at 0x7f179389e450>
<__main__.Dog object at 0x7f179389e510>
```

But it's not printing the property as it should be, and it doesn't appear to even be using the `__newstr__` function, because it's not printing `in newstr`.  However, if I check `bob.__str__`, I see that it is indeed `<function __newstr__ at 0x7f17951d78c0>`.

I must be missing something obvious, but I feel like this is over my head right now.  :/

Comment: If your question is about how to write decorators that take parameters, you might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/python-decorators-with-parameters).

Comment: Thanks, I've googled a lot and found some info like that, but what I'm trying to do is decorate a class and replace one of its methods, passing an argument to the constructor that changes the decorated class.  I can find plenty of examples of function decorators, function decorators with arguments, and class decorators, but I can't seem to find class decorators (that is, applying decorators to classes, not class-based function decorators) with arguments.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I guess it's not obvious to me.

Comment: The idea is the same.  If you read the question I linked, you'll see the answer says: "the decorator with arguments should return a function that will take a function and return another function".  The same applies to class decorators; it just means that the decorator with arguments should return a function that will take a class and return another class.  In other words, `strAs` needs to return the actual decorator.  Try adapting the answer there and asking a more specific question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks.  I did some rewriting and debugging, but I'm still quite stuck.  I guess there must be a lot of Python internals knowledge that I don't have that's necessary to work this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, I'd just let the decorator modify the class. Such as

```
class strAs:

    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop

    def __call__(self, cls):
        prop = self.prop
        def __str__(s):
            return getattr(s, prop)
        cls.__str__ = __str__
        return cls
```

Comment: Well, that is simple, and it works.  Thank you.  Now to figure out why my latest attempt didn't work.  It's like I was so close, but I was feeling around in the dark...

Comment: @blujay Your last version doesn't work because you are changing the instance's `__str__` instead of the class's one. That doesn't work. Even if it would, it wouldn't take the `self` argument, as it would operate on instance level.

Comment: Oh, I thought changing the instance's method was the way it was supposed to work.  I have a lot to learn.  Thanks for your help.