# Decorator taking a class and different parameters in input

Tags: python, python-decorators

I would like to create a decorator adding a logger to any decorated class. I succeeded with:

```
def logged(cls_to_decorate):
    log_name = cls_to_decorate.__module__
    logger = logging.getLogger(log_name)

    setattr(cls_to_decorate, 'logger', logger)
    return cls_to_decorate
```

Its usage:

```
@logged
class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def test_foo_function(self):
         self.logger.debug("ciao!!")
```

Now let's suppose I want to pass to this decorator an additional parameter, so to use it as follows:

```
@logged(logging_level=logging.DEBUG)
class TestFoo(TestCase):
    pass
```

I tried to use the syntax of the decorators for functions/methods (with wrapped function), but of course since we're talking about a class as parameter it doesn't work.

The decorator should be something like this:

```
...
def logged(cls_to_decorate, logging_level=None):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging_level)

    log_name = cls_to_decorate.__module__
    logger = logging.getLogger(log_name)

    setattr(cls_to_decorate, 'logger', logger)
    return cls_to_decorate
...
```

NOTE: the object to be decorated is a **class** and not a **function**.

Solution [python decorators with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/python-decorators-with-parameters) should apply, but I tried the following:

```
def logged(logging_level=None):
    def class_decorator(cls_to_decorate):

        # Do something with arguments
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging_level)
        log_name = cls_to_decorate.__module__
        logger = logging.getLogger(log_name)

        setattr(cls_to_decorate, 'logger', logger)
        return cls_to_decorate
    return class_decorator
```

But I have an error every time I wrap a class takling some argument:

```
E               TypeError: class_decorator() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nope, as the answer is about a function decorator...

Comment: the exact same principle applies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5929165/5827215) works the exact same way for a class as a function, create a nested factory function:

```
def decorator(argument):
    def real_decorator(class):
        <DECORATOR CODE HERE>
    return real_decorator
```

so you would do:

```
def logged(logging_level):
    def class_decorator(cls_to_decorate):
        log_name = cls_to_decorate.__module__
        logger = logging.getLogger(log_name)

        setattr(cls_to_decorate, 'logger', logger)
        return cls_to_decorate
    return class_decorator
```

Note that this means that you **must** call the decorator to use it as such, just using `@logged` will think that the class is the `logging_level` argument which makes no sense, you would need to at least do `@logged()` for it to work.

---

Although since you are using keywords anyway I'd like to offer an alternative using `functools.partial` when the call is missing information:

```
def logger(cls_to_decorate=None, logging_level=logging.DEBUG):
    if cls_to_decorate is None:
        return functools.partial(logger, logging_level=logging_level)

    ... #other code here
```

that way when you do `logger(existing_cls)` it works correctly and when you do `@logger(logging_level=logging.INFO)` it works correctly and just `@logged` works correctly, the only pitfall is if you accidentally specify the option in place of the class.

```
@logger(logging.INFO) #on no we passed a positional argument!!
class Test():pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py", line 25, in <module>
    @logged(logging.INFO)
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py", line 19, in logged
    log_name = cls_to_decorate.__module__
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

This is not the most informative error message although it can be improved by adding an `assert inspect.isclass(cls_to_decorate)` at some point.

Comment: `E               TypeError: class_decorator() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` when I try to call the target class (with some parameter, of course)

Comment: When you change `logged` to this you now **must** call it when using it as a decorator, `@logged()` would be sufficient.

Comment: you are correct. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AlexGidan, I just updated with the way I would do this using `partial`, you may or may not prefer it.