# Access parameters in parameterized decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to understand python decorator from this [doc](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/). And was writing my own decorator required to handle API Exceptions.

But in my decorator, I'm not getting how to access arguments (`method`, `api`, and  `data`) inside my Custom Decorator.

I know, I haven't passed `method` anywhere because I'm not getting where to pass so that I can accept it in my decorator.

Here is my decorator:

```
import requests as r
import json
def handle_api_exceptions(http_api_call):
    """ """

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """ """
        response = {}
        try:
            response = http_api_call(*args, **kwargs)
            if response.ok:
                result =  response.json()
                if result.get('code', 200) in INVALID_STATUS_CODES: #INVALID_STATUS_CODES = [1801, 1803, 1806,... ]
                    response = {"data":{}, "status":False}
                else:
                    return result
            else:
                capture_failed_requests(method, api, data, response, 
                                    error=None, reason=response.reason)
                return {}
        except r.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            capture_failed_requests(method, api, data, response, error=e,
                                         reason="Connection Aborted")
            return {}
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
            capture_failed_requests(method, api, data, response, error=e,
                                         reason="Invalid Response")
            return {}
        except r.exceptions.ReadTimeout as e:
            capture_failed_requests(method, api, data, response, error=e,
                                         reason="Request Timed Out")
            return {} 
        except Exception as e:
            capture_failed_requests(method, api, data, response, error=e,
                                         reason="Internal Server Error")
        return {}
    return wrapper
```

Custom GET, POST API requests:

```
@handle_api_exceptions
def get(self, api, data, token=None):
    """ """
    if token:data.update(self.get_token(token))
    response = r.get(api, data, verify=self.config.SSL_VERIFY,
                      timeout=self.config.REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
    return response

@handle_api_exceptions
def post(self, api, data, token=None):
    """ """
    if token:
        data.update(self.get_secret_token(token))
    response = r.post(api, data, verify=self.config.SSL_VERIFY,
                      timeout=self.config.REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
    return response        


def post_call(self):
    """ """
    api = "http://192.168.0.24/api/v1/reset/"
    data = {"k1":[], "k2":{}, "id":123456} #-- Some Key val
    return self.post(api, data, token="SOME_SECRET_TOKEN")
```

Query is : How to pass `method`, `api`, and  `data` in `capture_failed_requests()`?

Comment: You can't pass `method` as currently written, but `data` and `api` are just in `args`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : can I pass hard coded method="GET" or method="POST" from somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you could pass that to the decorator directly: `@handle_api_exceptions(method='GET')`. Bear in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5929107/3001761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` and `api` are in the `args` inside `wrapper`. `method` you will have to provide separately, e.g. by parameterising the decorator (see e.g. [python decorators with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5929107/3001761)). You could therefore do this as follows:

```
def handle_api_exceptions(method):
    def decorator(http_api_call): 
        def wrapper(api, data, *args, **kwargs):
            ...
```

and your decorating would become e.g.

```
@handle_api_exceptions(method='GET')
def get(self, api, data, token=None):
    ...
```

Alternatively, you could use `method = http_api_call.__name__` (which would give you `'get'`), and avoid the extra layer of nesting and duplication of the method name.

---

Note that I have removed the empty docstrings - either write an actual docstring (I like [Google-style](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html), but YMMV) or don't have one at all. If your linting rules *require* docstrings, that's because whoever set it up wants you to write *useful* ones, not just cheat on it.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. Also one more +1 for Google Style suggestion, Appreciated :)