# Python decorators with arguments

Tags: python, decorator

I'm having trouble understanding the concept of decorators, so basically if I understood correctly, decorators are used to extend the behavior of a function, without modifying the functions code . The basic example:

I have the decorator function, which take as parameter another function and then changes the functionality of the function given as argument:

```
def decorator(f):
  def wrapper(*args):
    return "Hello " + str(f(*args))
return wrapper
```

And here I have the function which I want to decorate :

```
@decorator
def text (txt):
'''function that returns the txt argument'''
  return txt
```

So if I understand correctly  , what actually happens "behind" is:

```
d=decorator(text)
d('some argument')
```

My question is , what happens in this case when we have three nested function in the decorator:

```
def my_function(argument):
   def decorator(f):
     def wrapper(*args):
        return "Hello " +str(argument)+ str(f(*args))
    return wrapper
return decorator

@my_function("Name ")
def text(txt):
  return txt
```

Because the functionality is awesome, I can pass argument in the decorator, I do not understand what actually happens behind this call :

```
@my_function("Name ")
```

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python decorators with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/python-decorators-with-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just another level of indirection, basically the code is equivalent to:

```
decorator = my_function("Name ")
decorated = decorator(text)
text = decorated
```

Without arguments, you already have the decorator, so

```
decorated = my_function(text)
text = decorated
```

Answer (score 1):

`my_function` is used to create a closure here. The `argument` is local to `my_function`. But due to closure, when you return the `decorator`, the `decorator` function has a reference to it all the time. So when you apply `decorator` to `text`, the `decorator` adds extra functionality, as to be expected. It also can embed `argument` in its extra functionality since it has access to the environment in which it was defined.