# How to create a decorator with arguments that will parse request?

Tags: python, decorator

I have the following method:

```
@try_except_decorator
@json_response_decorator
async def find_videos_in_polygon(request):
    points = request.query['points']
    end_date = request.query['end_date']
    start_date = request.query['start_date']
    ding_kind = request.query.get('ding_kind', 'all')

    search_service = request.app['search_service']
    data = await search_service.search_in_polygon(points, start_date,
                                              end_date,
                                              ding_kind=ding_kind,
                                              doorbot_kind=doorbot_kind)

    return {'videos': data}
```

How to create a decorator that will parse request? I wanna to have something like this:

```
@try_except_decorator
@json_response_decorator
@parse_request('points', 'end_date', 'start_date', ('ding_kind', 'all'))
async def find_videos_in_polygon(request):
    search_service = request.app['search_service']
    data = await search_service.search_in_polygon(???)

    return {'videos': data}
```

Also, I don't want to change signature of `find_videos_in_polygon(request)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decorators with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters)

Comment: So what is your problem exactly? What code do you have for `parse_request` now?

Comment: I don't know how to implement `@parse_request()` decorator and use parsed parameters inside `search_service.search_in_polygon(...)` as I did it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want to inject some variables to the function scope every time it is invoked. One way to do this would be to temporarily insert data to the function's globals scope(`find_videos_in_polygon.__globals__`) and later clean it up.

```
def inject_variables(func, _new_values=None):
    for k, v in _new_values.items():
        func.__globals__[k] = v


def cleanup_variables(func, _default=None, _new_values=None, _old_values=None):
    """
    Reset function's global scope with data in `_old_value`.
    If a particular key's value is sentinel then it means the
    key didn't exist and we can remove it.
    """
    for k, v in _old_values.items():
        old_value = _old_values[k]
        if old_value is _default:
            del func.__globals__[k]
        else:
            func.__globals__[k] = old_value


def parse_request(*names):
    def decorator(func):
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            request = args[0]
            new_values = {}
            current_global_values = {}
            sentinel = object()

            for var in names:
                name = var
                if isinstance(var, tuple):
                    name, value = var
                    new_values[name] = request.query.get(name, value)
                else:
                    try:
                        new_values[name] = request.query[name]
                    except KeyError:
                        raise UnboundLocalError("local variable '{name}' referenced before assignment".format(
                            name=name
                        ))
                current_global_values[name] = func.__globals__.get(name, sentinel)

            inject_variables(func, _new_values=new_values)
            val = await func(*args, **kwargs)
            cleanup_variables(func, _default=sentinel, _new_values=new_values, _old_values=current_global_values)
            return val
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

**Test code:**

```
from asyncio import get_event_loop


missing = 10000

@parse_request('foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs', ('missing', '10'))
async def func(request):
    print(foo, bar, spam, eggs, missing)


class Request:
    pass


loop = get_event_loop()

Request.query = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'spam': 3, 'eggs': 4}
loop.run_until_complete(func(Request))
print(missing)

Request.query = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'spam': 3, 'eggs': 4, 'missing': 15}
loop.run_until_complete(func(Request))
print(missing)

# Missing required key 'eggs', should raise an error
Request.query = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'spam': 3}
loop.run_until_complete(func(Request))
print(missing)
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 10
10000
1 2 3 4 15
10000
... 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'eggs' referenced before assignment
```

---

But of course, doing something like this would make the code less-readable and hard to debug. Hence it is better to be explicit and do things that are much easier to understand and test. I would recommend adding a helper function that can parse and return a dict with all keyword arguments expected by `search_in_polygon`.

```
def parse_request(request, *names):
    data = {}
    for var in names:
        name = var
        if isinstance(var, tuple):
            name, value = var
            data[name] = request.query.get(name, value)
        else:
            data[name] = request.query[name]
    return data


async def func(request):
    request_data = parse_request(request, 'foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'eggs', ('missing', '10'))
    print(request_data)
    # data = await search_in_polygon(**request_data)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> Request.query = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'spam': 3, 'eggs': 4}
>>> loop.run_until_complete(func(Request))
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'spam': 3, 'eggs': 4, 'missing': '10'}
>>> Request.query = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'spam': 3, 'eggs': 4, 'missing': 15}
>>> loop.run_until_complete(func(Request))
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'spam': 3, 'eggs': 4, 'missing': 15}
>>> Request.query = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'spam': 3}
>>> loop.run_until_complete(func(Request))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError: 'eggs'
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use this kind of pattern:

```
from functools import wraps

def your_decorator(arg1, arg2, arg3, kwarg1=None):
    def wrapper(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            # Do things with arg1, arg2, arg3 and kwarg1
            # if the inner function `f` needs to access these arguments, you need to pass it in somehow.
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper
```