# Decorators with parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, docstring

I have a collection of functions with (mostly) shared parameters but different processes.  I'd like to use a decorator to add the description for each parameter to a function's headline-level docstring.

I've tried to mimic the structure found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5929165/7954504) by incorporating a nested function within `appender` but failed.  I've also tried `functools.partial` but something is slightly off.

My attempt:

```
def appender(func, *args):
    """Appends additional parameter descriptions to func's __doc__."""
    def _doc(func):
        params = ''.join([defaultdocs[arg] for arg in args])
        func.__doc__ += '\n' + params
        return func
    return _doc

defaultdocs = {

    'a' : 
    """
    a : int, default 0
        the first parameter
    """,

    'b' : 
    """
    b : int, default 1
        the second parameter
    """
    }

@appender('a')
def f(a):
    """Title-level docstring."""
    return a 

@appender('a', 'b')
def g(a, b):
    """Title-level docstring."""
    return a + b
```

This fails, and it fails I believe because the first arg passed to `appender` is interpreted as `func`.  So when I view the resulting docstring for `g` I get:

```
print(g.__doc__)
Title-level docstring.

    b : int, default 1
        the second parameter
```

because, again, `'a'` is interpreted to be `'func'` when I want it to be the first element of `*args`.  How can I correct this?

Desired result:

```
print(g.__doc__)
Title-level docstring.

    a : int, default 0
        the first parameter

    b : int, default 1
        the second parameter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the variable names you pass actually get captured into a `func` argument.

In order to do callable decorators in Python you need to code the function twice, having **external** function to accept decorator arguments and **internal** function to accept original function. Callable decorators are just higher-order functions that return other decorators. For example:

```
def appender(*args):  # This is called when a decorator is called,
                      # e. g. @appender('a', 'b')
    """Appends additional parameter descriptions to func's __doc__."""
    def _doc(func):  # This is called when the function is about
                     # to be decorated
        params = ''.join([defaultdocs[arg] for arg in args])
        func.__doc__ += '\n' + params
        return func
    return _doc
```

The external (`appender`) function acts as a factory for new decorator while `_doc` function is an actual decorator. Always pass it this way:

- Pass decorator args to the external function
- Pass original function to the internal function

Once the Python sees this:

```
@appender('a', 'b')
def foo(): pass
```

...it will do something like this under the hood:

```
foo = appender('a', 'b')(foo)
```

...which expands to this:

```
decorator = appender('a', 'b')
foo = decorator(foo)
```

Because of how scopes in Python work, each newly returned `_doc` function instance will have its own local `args` value from the external function.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution that uses `inspect.signature` to collect the passed function params.

```
import inspect
import textwrap

def appender(defaultdocs):
    def _doc(func):
        params = inspect.signature(func).parameters 
        params = [param.name for param in params.values()] 
        params = ''.join([textwrap.dedent(defaultdocs[param]) 
                      for param in params])
        func.__doc__ += '\n\nParameters\n' + 10 * '=' + params
        return func

    return _doc
```

Example:

```
# default docstrings for parameters that are re-used often
# class implementation not a good alternative in my specific case

defaultdocs = {

    'a' : 
    """
    a : int, default 0
        the first parameter""",

    'b' : 
    """
    b : int, default 1
        the second parameter"""
    }

@appender
def f(a):
    """Title-level docstring."""
    return a

@appender
def g(a, b):
    """Title-level docstring."""
    return a + b
```

This appends the descriptions for `a` and `b` to `g.__doc__` without needing to specify them in the decorator:

```
help(g)
Help on function g in module __main__:

g(a, b)
    Title-level docstring.

    Parameters
    ==========
    a : int, default 0
        the first parameter
    b : int, default 1
        the second parameter
```