# Decoraters in class object while passing class variables

Tags: python, pyqt4, decorator, pyside

I am wondering how I can setup a decorator in a class that can accept class variables. The example where I think this could be useful is in Pyside/PyQt where I need to block and unblock signals on widgets at the beginning and ending of functions.

Example:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    ....

    def updateList(self, *args):
        self.list.blockSignals(False)
        //do things on self.list
        self.list.blockSignals(True)
```

Now, there is the potential of a lots of places on different widgets this could be done. Sure I can do this method of blocking and unblocking each item, but that's tedious. And I have to remember to unblock everything when I'm done.

Moving into another step, I can move the blocking into it's own function.

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    ....

    def updateList(self, *args):
        self.block([self.list])
        //do things on self.list
        self.block([self.list])

    def block(self, items):
        for item in items:
            if item.signalsBlocked():
                item.blockSignals(False)
            else:
                item.blockSignals(True)
```

Sweet! I can pepper that around my code and feels pretty useful. But I feel like there is some kind of final boss form I'm missing here to make it truely globally useful. Like some kind of decorator.

Using this answer here I can pass variables to my decorator and decorate my function!
[Decorators with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters)

```
def block(items):
    def dec(fn):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            for item in items:
                item.blockSignals(True)
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
            for item in items:
                item.blockSignals(False)
        return wrapped
    return dec


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    ....

    @block([self.list])
    def updateList(self, *args):
        //do things on self.list
```

Now I feel that could truly be useful! Except, @block([self.list]) has no idea what self is.

So, what I'm attempting to do, is that reasonable to assume I can do this? Is it possible, or am I chasing wild dragons? If it's possible, what's the correct way to attempt this?

Comment: @DavisHerring ah yes, I looked at the other answer again, I fixed it.

Comment: (cleaning up comments...)

Comment: This should be a context manager, rather than a decorator. It would be much more flexible that way, since it wouldn't be tied to any particular object or function/method.

Comment: @ekhumoro: It could easily be both.

Comment: @ekhumoro could you provide an example? I'm unfamiliar with them and doing a little bit of research so far, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @ooklah. See my answer for a simple example. I think context managers are much easier to reason about than decorators, and can provide a very clean and flexible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to the attribute *values* at class definition time, but you can use their names:

```
def block(*attrs):
    def dec(fn):
        @functools.wraps(fn)
        def wrap(self,*args,**kwargs):
            for a in attrs: getattr(self,a).blockSignals(True)
            ret=fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
            for a in attrs: getattr(self,a).blockSignals(False)
            return ret
        return wrap
    return dec
```

It's a bit ugly to have to write

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    @block("list1","list2")
    def updateList(self, *args): # ...
```

with the string quotes and all, but it works.

Comment: I think I would have used `instance` as the parameter name instead of `self` in `wrap` - but ...

Comment: `instance` would conflict with an argument of the same name in the wrapped function.  The function `wrap` will become a method of the class as soon as the descriptor returns it, `self` seems perfectly idiomatic to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple context manager, for comparison:

```
class blocked(object):
    def __init__(self, *targets):
        self._targets = targets

    def __enter__(self):
        for target in self._targets:
            target.blockSignals(True)

    def __exit__(self, cls, exception, traceback):
        for target in self._targets:
            target.blockSignals(False)
```

and here's how to use it:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    ...

    def updateList(self, *args):
        with blocked(self.list):
            # do things with self.list
```

The benefit of doing things this way is that `blocked` can be used *anywhere*, and the targets can be specified dynamically. It could also be argued that it is more readable, since it is `self.list` (the signal emitter) that is being blocked, not `self.updateList`.

Comment: I can immediately see where that's useful when the signals should not be blocked for the entire function. A decorator would blanket block the entire function in these examples.