# Can a decorator returning a non-callable take additional arguments?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have subclassed the built-in `property` class (call it `SpecialProperty`) in order to add more fields to it:

```
class SpecialProperty(property):
    extra_field_1 = None
    extra_field_2 = None
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        super().__init__(fget, fset, fdel, doc)

def make_special_property(func):
    prop = SerialisableProperty(fget=func)
    return prop
```

and I am able to use it in the same fashion as the built-in `property()` decorator:

```
@my_module.make_special_property
def get_my_property(self): return self._my_property
```

I now want to further specialise my `SpecialProperty` instances populating one of the extra fields I have added to the class with an arbitrary value.

**Is it possible, in Python, to write a decorator that will return a property with also accepting extra parameters?**

I'd like to do it via the decorator because this is where and when the information is most relevant, however I'm finding myself stuck. I suspect this falls under the domain of *decorators with arguments* that have been well documented ([Decorators with arguments? (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters), or [Python Decorators II: Decorator Arguments (artima.com)](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845) to only cite a couple sources), however I find myself unable to apply the same pattern to my case.

Here's how I'm trying to write it:

```
@my_module.make_special_property("example string")
def get_my_property(self): return self._my_property
```

And on the class declaring `get_my_property`:

```
>>> DeclaringClass.my_property
<SpecialProperty object at 0x...>
>>> DeclaringClass.my_property.extra_field_1
'example string'
```

Since I am making `properties`, the decorated class member should be swapped with an instance of `SpecialProperty`, and hence should not be a callable anymore -- thus, I am unable to apply the "nested wrapper" pattern for allowing a decorator with arguments.

Non working example:

```
def make_special_property(custom_arg_1):
    def wrapper(func):
        prop = SerialisableProperty(fget=func)
        prop.extra_field_1 = custom_arg_1
        return prop
    return wrapper # this returns a callable (function)
```

I shouldn't have a callable be returned here, if I want a property I should have a `SpecialProperty` instance be returned, but I can't call `return wrapper(func)` for obvious reasons.

Comment: This works fine for me - in both cases, `SomeClass.get_my_property` returns a `SpecialProperty`. Are you sure you tested things properly? What result were you expecting, and how does that differ from what you actually get?

Comment: HI, yes -- this part works for me as I've explained above. I have added details on what I'm trying to do. Instead of simply decorating with `@make_special_property` I want to pass it an argument like `@make_special_property(arg)`, and that should set a field within the `SpecialProperty` instance (for example,  `SomeClass.get_my_property.extra_field_1` would return `arg`). I'm hitting a language barrier it seems, since I can't seem to be able to write code that would allow me that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes I have shown that I *can* do that, but I can't pass the decorator an argument. The pattern for passing extra arguments to decorators works when the decorator returns a callable, not when it's a non-callable object -- such as `property`.

Comment: You should see the decorator syntax like this `@<expression>` where `<expression>` is a callable that will take the function to decorate as argument: `func = <expression>(func)`. If `<expression>` is a function name, like `@property`, it will call `your_func = property(your_func)`. If `<expression>` is a call, like `@functools.lru_cache()`, it will call `your_func = functools.lru_cache()(your_func)`.

Comment: @korrigan. As I said above - it all works perfectly fine for me. I used what you are calling "Non working example" without any changes and applied it as `@make_special_property('foo')` to a normal method. After that, `SomeClass.get_my_property.custom_arg_1` returns `"foo"` exactly as expected, and `SomeClass.get_my_property` returns an instance of `SpecialProperty`. Also, `x = SomeClass(); x.get_my_property` behaves as a normal attribute/property. Please explain more clearly why you think the code doesn't work.

Comment: @ekhumoro my bad, you are correct. I have been confused by an interaction with another part of my code. After reducing my case to the one I stated above, I could see that it was indeed working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your decorator doesn't return a callable. Your decorator factory returns a decorator, which returns a property. You might understand better if you rename the functions:

```
def make_decorator(custom_arg_1):
    def decorator(func):
        prop = SerialisableProperty(fget=func)
        prop.extra_field_1 = custom_arg_1
        return prop
    return decorator
```

When you decorate with `make_decorator`, it is called with an argument, and `decorator` is returned and called on the decorated function.