# Undertanding decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators

the task is to call a function 4 times using decorator. The solution is:

```
def my_decorator (func):
    def wrapper():
        func()
        func()
        func()
        func()
    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def printer_hp():
    print('I am printer HP 4700 LaserJet')
    return 0

printer_hp()
```

HOWEVER, if I move *func* to the wrapper args and put parentheses for the @my_decorator:

```
def my_decorator ():
    def wrapper(func):
        func()
        func()
        func()
        func()
    return wrapper

@my_decorator()
def printer_hp():
    print('I am printer HP 4700 LaserJet')
    return 0
```

the function is called automatically 4 times without calling it in the main program.
Why is that?

Comment: There is a great (though lengthy) explanation, that really helps understanding decorators: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators/1594484#1594484

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you do:

```
@my_decorator()
def printer_hp():
    ...
```

It is equivalent to:

```
printer_hp = my_decorator()(printer_hp)
```

Since `my_decorator()` returns `wrapper`, it is then equivalent to:

```
printer_hp = wrapper(printer_hp)
```

And what `wrapper` does is call the given function 4 times, which is why `printer_hp` is called 4 times right away.

Comment: Was typing up something similar. Might want to include that with `()` basically follows the same behavior as decorators with arguments. Here's a good thread on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters

You'd basically want a third outer function to accept the decorator's args; in this case, none.