# Use decorators to call function without arguments

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

In an effort to make my code clearer for (mostly) myself to read, I was attempting to use decorators to put most of the function arguments inside `@decorator(args)`, and then calling the function without arguments. This is my current code:

```py
def dec1(*args, **kwargs):
    def dec2(func):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return dec2

@dec1(1, 2, 3)
def func1(val1, val2, val3):
    print(val1)
    print(val2)
    print(val3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1()
```

However, it is reporting this (essentially running the code using the decorator, but not the second function call):

```py
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shadowrylander/decorator_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    f1()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What I am trying the accomplish is similar to what the [`Click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) library does (defining `hello()` with arguments, then later calling it with none):

```py
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
def hello(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me create a decorator similar to this, and I apologize if this has already been asked and/or answered before; I either could not understand them properly or could not find the question! 
Thank you kindly for the help!

Comment: Why does your function even take those arguments, if you just want to use hardcoded values?

Comment: Change `func1` to `func` in your decorator. When you are calling the wrapper function `func1` refers to the decorated function, not the original definition.

Comment: A decorator with arguments is expected to return the real decorator. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters. Also see functools.partial

Comment: Also, the error you've posted is not the error produced by the posted version of your code.

Comment: @user2357112: just for illustration purposes; I wanted to use pretty much any function with a decorator that can take any arguments and pass it over!

Comment: @Bakuriu: Whoops; my bad! Editing now!

Comment: @VPfB: Reading through it now!

Comment: @user2357112: Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dec2` you are returning the result of calling `func1` with the specified arguments, which is not what you want.

What you want is returning a function `f` which calls `func1` with the specified arguments, that is:

```
def dec1(*args, **kwargs):
    def dec2(func):
        def f():
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return f
    return dec2
```

**A more detailed explanation:**

Remember that the decorator syntax:

```
@dec1(1, 2, 3)
def func1(val1, val2, val3):
    ...
```

is syntactically equivalent to:

```
def func1(val1, val2, val3):
    ...
func1 = dec1(1, 2, 3)(func1)
```

so the result of `dec1(...)` (`dec2`) is called with the decorated function (`func1`) as argument at the time you decorate the function. So you don't want `dec2` to do anything but return a function that will do something later when it's called.

Comment: That was it! Thanks!