# How to type-annotate a decorator that has an optional parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Here's the exact function that I'm trying to type-annotate correctly:

```
F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])

def throttle(_func: Optional[F] = None, *, rate: float = 1) -> Union[F, Callable[[F], F]]:
    """Throttles a function call, so that at minimum it can be called every `rate` seconds.

    Usage::

        # this will enforce the default minimum time of 1 second between function calls
        @throttle
        def ...

    or::

        # this will enforce a custom minimum time of 2.5 seconds between function calls
        @throttle(rate=2.5)
        def ...

    This will raise an error, because `rate=` needs to be specified::

        @throttle(5)
        def ...
    """

    def decorator(func: F) -> F:
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
            time.sleep(rate)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return cast(F, wrapper)

    if _func is None:
        return decorator
    else:
        return decorator(_func)
```

While I'm not getting any error when putting it through mypy, I'm not convinced that I did the right thing, nor am I sure how I could go about proving it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code typechecks but probably it does not do what you want, because you are returning an `Union`.

To check what type mypy infers for some variable you can use `reveal_type`.

```py
# Note: I am assuming you meant "throttle" and so I changed your spelling
def throttle1(
    _func: Optional[F] = None, *, rate: float = 1.0
) -> Union[F, Callable[[F], F]]:
    # code omitted


@throttle1
def hello1() -> int:
    return 42


reveal_type(hello1) # Revealed type is 'Union[def () -> builtins.int, def (def () -> builtins.int) -> def () -> builtins.int]'
```

Assuming we want `hello1` to be a function that returns an int (i.e. `def () -> builtins.int`) we need to try something else.

### Simple strategy

The simplest thing is to always ask the user of `throttle` to "call the decorator" even if she/he is not overriding any arguments:

```py
def throttle2(*, rate: float = 1.0) -> Callable[[F], F]:
    def decorator(func: F) -> F:
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
            time.sleep(rate)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return cast(F, wrapper)

    return decorator


@throttle2() # Note that I am calling throttle2 without arguments
def hello2() -> int:
    return 42

reveal_type(hello2) # Revealed type is 'def () -> builtins.int'


@throttle2(rate=2.0)
def hello3() -> int:
    return 42

reveal_type(hello3) # Revealed type is 'def () -> builtins.int'
```

This already works and is very simple.

### Use `typing.overload`

In case the previous solution is not acceptable, you can use `overload`.

```
# Matches when we are overriding some arguments
@overload
def throttle3(_func: None = None, *, rate: float = 1.0) -> Callable[[F], F]:
    ...

# Matches when we are not overriding any argument
@overload
def throttle3(_func: F) -> F:
    ...


def throttle3(
    _func: Optional[F] = None, *, rate: float = 1.0
) -> Union[F, Callable[[F], F]]:
    # your original code goes here


@throttle3 # Note: we do not need to call the decorator
def hello4() -> int:
    return 42


reveal_type(hello4) # Revealed type is 'def () -> builtins.int'


@throttle3(rate=2.0)
def hello5() -> int:
    return 42


reveal_type(hello5) # Revealed type is 'def () -> builtins.int'
```

You can learn more on how to use `overload` by reading [its official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload), and [mypy's documentation on Function overloading](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#function-overloading).

Comment: the part from "Use typing.overload" doesn't work though, mypy just gives other errors

Comment: check out this gist please, where everything seems to work fine https://gist.github.com/Laurentiu-Andronache/505908e99e299e55070a644e8ff24187

Comment: Umh, you are right. I think the problem is that ellipsis (`...`) can be used as default only in stub files. If you don't want to use a stub file, I think the only thing is to write again the default values. I will update the answer :)

Comment: you also have to remove the typing from the actual definition `def throttle3(
    _func: Optional[F] = None, *, rate: float = 1.0
) -> Union[F, Callable[[F], F]]:`

Comment: and the first overload doesn't need `_func`

Comment: I might be wrong, I'm just telling you what I did in the gist and doesn't get errors out of mypy

Comment: I'm reading now your second answer btw, thank you so much for the time that you've put into this!

Comment: Your code works, but I think that by not annotating the implementation of throttle you lose the type checking inside the function. Therefore, I usually try to annotate everything.

Comment: Hmm yeah, if I run `mypy --strict`, I get `Function is missing a type annotation`, even though they're specified in the @overload. That's like a mypy bug if you ask me. Unrelated, as I said above, your first overload doesn't need `_func: None = None, `

Comment: What a beautiful solution with the 'simple strategy'!
Thanks a lot! I've spent days trying to both properly annotate my parametrized decorator and make mypy/pyright happy at the same time...