# how to create a decorator for a method

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator

I want to decorate a simple method, to run 5 times:

```
def do_5(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wr(*a,**kw):
        i = 0
        while i < 5:
            f(a,kw)
            i += 1
    return wr

class a(object):
    @do_5
    def f(self, x):
        print x
```

however, this only makes the func print `{}` where x is actually 1

Using ipdb I saw that `self` is the first of `*a` so I tried changing the wrapper to

```
In [37]:     def do_5(f):
    ...:         @wraps(f)
    ...:         def wr(*a,**kw):
    ...:             self, other_args = a[0], a[1:]
    ...:             i = 0
    ...:             while i < 5:
    ...:                 f(self,other_args,kw)
    ...:                  i += 1
    ...:         return wr
```

and

```
In [37]:     def do_5(f):
    ...:         @wraps(f)
    ...:         def wr(*a,**kw):
    ...:             self, other_args = a[0], a[1:]
    ...:             i = 0
    ...:             while i < 5:
    ...:                 self.f(other_args,kw)
    ...:                  i += 1
    ...:         return wr
```

but got:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

and

```
TypeError: f() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

respectively

How can I solve this?

*BTW, can I make this decorator dynamic, as in @do_n(f, n) and decorate it like so (`@do_n(100)`) and just use the `n` instead of 5 in the wrapper?*

Comment: `while i < 5:` - you never do `i += 1` ?

Comment: stupid mistake. But now it only fixes the infinite recursion, it's not the main issue of the question

Comment: You still need to unpack the arguments passed to the wrapper: `f(*a, **kw)`. Otherwise, you are just passing two arguments to `f`: a tuple and a dict.

Comment: @CIsForCookies Re *making this decorator dynamic*; i.e. making a decorator with parameters: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define the wrapper with parameters `*a` and `**kw`, `a` is a tuple and `kw` is a dict. The `*` and `**` in a function *definition* are a signal to collect arguments into the two parameters when the function is called. You are passing those two objects to `f`, rather than the arguments *contained* in them. You need to unpack them in the call to the wrapped function. In a *call*, `*` and `**` *unpack* the attached names.

```
def do_5(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wr(*a,**kw):
        i = 0
        while i < 5:
            f(*a, **kw)
            i += 1
    return wr
```

Now, `a().f(3)` will output

```
3
3
3
3
3
```

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data forwards as it is, `f(*a,**kw)`, a is a tuple and kw is dict.

```
from functools import wraps


def do_5(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wr(*a,**kw):
        i = 0
        while i < 5:
            f(*a,**kw)
            i += 1
    return wr

class a(object):
    @do_5
    def f(self, x):
        print x

b = a()
b.f(1)
```