# Decorator returns function but 'str' is returned instead?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'm practicing decorators and have the following code:

```
def p_decorate(a, b):
    def real_decorator(func):
        return func(a, b) + func(a, b)
    return real_decorator


@p_decorate(a="a", b="b")
def get_text(x, z):
    return '{}---{}'.format(x, z)

print(get_text('A', 'B'))
```

And i get the following error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

Why ? I **am** returning a function and not a function call so why does it return 'str' instead ??

Comment: use `from functools import wraps

def p_decorate(a, b):
    def real_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         return func(a, b)
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator` source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42581103/6622587

Comment: But where is my mistake in the code ? I can't see why it's wrong

Comment: Because you need an internal function more if you are going to pass the arguments to the decorator, in your case your logic is for a decorator without arguments, review the answers and understand clearly.

Comment: `def p_decorate(arg1, arg2):
    def real_decorator(func):
        def wrap(*args):
            return func(*args) + func(*args)
        return wrap
    return real_decorator


@p_decorate("arg1", "arg2")
def get_text(x, z):
    return f'{x}---{z}'


print(get_text('A', 'B'))
` You need a function in the real_decorator function of yours for the arguments. Hope this helps. Sorry for the bad formatting. This outputs `A---BA---B`.