# Change in interpreted behaviour upon introduction of del keyword

Tags: python-3.x, interpreter

I wrote the following toy:

```
def foo():
    x = 5
    def foo2():
        print("Locals: ", locals())
        print("Vars: ", vars())
        print("dir: ", dir())
        print("CP 1")
        print("x =", x)
        print("CP 2")
        print("Locals: ", locals())
        print("Vars: ", vars())
        print("dir: ", dir())
    foo2()

foo()

print("-----------------------")

def foo():
    x = 5
    def foo2():
        print("Locals: ", locals())
        print("Vars: ", vars())
        print("dir: ", dir())
        print("CP 1")
        print("x =", x)
        print("CP 2")
        del x
        print("Locals: ", locals())
        print("Vars: ", vars())
        print("dir: ", dir())
    foo2()

foo()
```

which produces the following output:

```
Locals:  {'x': 5}
Vars:  {'x': 5}
dir:  ['x']
CP 1
x = 5
CP 2
Locals:  {'x': 5}
Vars:  {'x': 5}
dir:  ['x']
-----------------------
Locals:  {}
Vars:  {}
dir:  []
CP 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 34, in <module>
    foo()
  File "testing.py", line 32, in foo
    foo2()
  File "testing.py", line 26, in foo2
    print("x =", x)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

Notice how behaviour of the second edition is modified even in the areas of the code up to which the two editions are identical (and thus should produce identical outcomes). Since x, according to the first edition, does exist in the local namespace, the del statement shouldn't be an issue.

Questions:

1) Is the first or second edition 'right'? Should x exist in the namespace or not?

2) Is there an explanation for this behaviour or is it a bug?

(Follow up to 2: 3) Should the second edition run without an error or is it supposed to crash?)

Comment: Related: [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370357/4518341)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Answer (score 1):

The `del x` triggers the interpreter into shadowing the non-local `x` variable defined outside `foo2()`'s frame.

The same effect would be obtained if you were to replace `del x` with `x = ...`  at the very same position.

The reason for this is that `x` is actually on the same level as `foo2()` and when `del x` is reached during `foo2()`, the interpreter decides not that the name `x` should be reserved for a local variable `x`, and hence it does not update your `locals()` with the name from it's outer name. Moving the `x` assignment inside `foo2()` would let `x` be truly `local` and hence appear in `locals()`:

```
def foo():
    def foo2():
        x = 5
        print("Locals: ", locals())
        print("Vars: ", vars())
        print("dir: ", dir())
        print("CP 1")
        print("x =", x)
        print("CP 2")
        del x
        print("Locals: ", locals())
        print("Vars: ", vars())
        print("dir: ", dir())
    foo2()

foo()
```

```
Locals:  {'x': 5}
Vars:  {'x': 5}
dir:  ['x']
CP 1
x = 5
CP 2
Locals:  {}
Vars:  {}
dir:  []
```

as well as declaring `x` to refer to the `nonlocal` variable explicitly inside `foo2()`:

```
def foo():
    x = 5
    def foo2():
        nonlocal x
        print("Locals: ", locals())
        print("Vars: ", vars())
        print("dir: ", dir())
        print("CP 1")
        print("x =", x)
        print("CP 2")
        del x
        print("Locals: ", locals())
        print("Vars: ", vars())
        print("dir: ", dir())
    foo2()

foo()
```

```
Locals:  {'x': 5}
Vars:  {'x': 5}
dir:  ['x']
CP 1
x = 5
CP 2
Locals:  {}
Vars:  {}
dir:  []
```

Comment: This is somewhat similar to the scoping behaviors observed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57691284/5218354).

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. Why would the del be executed at definition time? If it were, then something like 

>>> def g():
...     l = [1, 2, 3]
...     print(l)
...     del l
... 
>>> g()
[1, 2, 3]

wouldn't work and there'd be no point to the keyword.

Comment: @EdwardGaremo Sorry, the explanation was misleading. I have now improved it.

Comment: I still don't understand thought. I understand that assigning x within foo2 shadows the one in foo, but shouldn't this only be evident AFTER the relevant line, x = ... or del x is executed? 

(I think I have a misconceived notion of the execution model: I thought that, as an interpreted language, each line of python is executed one after the other - but your answer (and the behaviour) implies a sort of lookahead)

Comment: Is it not possible to do something like

  def foo():
      x = 'Non-local x'
      def foo2():
          print(x)
          x = 'Local x'
          print(x)
      foo2()

  foo()

?

Comment: @EdwardGaremo [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370380/5218354) from the proposed duplicate should be clearing the underlying mechanisms for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but it's probably worth making a separate post asking for clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following post solved it for me:

https://amir.rachum.com/blog/2013/07/09/python-common-newbie-mistakes-part-2/

I would like highlight:

"The first misconception is that Python, being an interpreted language (which is awesome, I think we can all agree), is executed line-by-line. In truth, Python is being executed statement-by-statement. To get a feel of what I mean, go to your favorite shell (you aren’t using the default one, I hope) and type the following:

```
def foo():
```

Press Enter. As you can see, the shell didn’t offer any output and it’s clearly waiting for you to continue with your function definition."

This was the source of my confusion.

Thanks to @norok2 for pointing me to a post which pointed me to this.

(https://docs.python.org/3.1/faq/programming.html?highlight=nonlocal#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

was also helpful)