# How do I make a dummy do-nothing @jit decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, numba

I want numba to be an optional dependency, so that it's fast if installed or slow if not.  So when numba is not installed, I want `@njit` to be a dummy decorator that does nothing.

If I follow [these directions](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/03/simple-python-decorator-examples/) and use:

```
def njit(func):
    return func
```

Then when the decorator is called like `@njit(cache=True, nogil=True)` I get errors about:

> `TypeError: njit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cache'`

If I try to catch the args and ignore them using

```
    def njit(func, *args, **kwargs):
        return func
```

then I get:

> `missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`

How do I just make a dummy decorator that does nothing and ignores kwargs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decorators with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think of decorators with arguments as decorator factory, they return a decorator. This way

```
def decorator(func):
    return func
```

The above is a decorator, now with arguments

```
def decorator_factory(a,b,c):
    def decorator(func):
        return func
    return decorator
```

The inner `decorator` has access to the `a,b,c` arguments because it is a closure. I hope that helps

---

So it can be defined as:

```
def njit(cache, nogil):
    def decorator(func):
        return func 
    return decorator
```

Comment: Yep that fixes it.      ```def njit(*args, **kwargs):
        def decorator(func):
            return func
        return decorator```

Comment: @endolith: Only if you always do `@njit()` and never `@njit`. It will silently do the wrong thing if you ever do `@njit`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save some time and be able to do the same with all numba decorators, try [numbasub](https://github.com/ptooley/numbasub). It provides exactly what you are asking for, and you can apply it to any project you want.

Comment: that would just be another dependency, though?

Comment: true. it's a very light dependency though since it has no dependencies itself. Plus it covers a lot of cases that are annoying to address one by one, e.g. if numba types are imported somewhere in the code you would have to mock them one by one. 
But if one only needs to create dummies for a couple of decorators, it might be overkill (it's even mentioned in the readme file).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on geckos' answer, we can adapt it to be compatible with @njit as well.

The code for jit can be found in https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/main/numba/core/decorators.py

What we need to do is to make jit act as a factory decorator when used as @jit() and as a simple decorator when used as @jit.

```
def njit(f=None, *args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        return func 

    if callable(f):
        return f
    else:
        return decorator
```

This should work in both cases.