# How to Create a Decorator Class that takes Arguments while Using `functools.wraps` and Preserving Access to the Decorated Instance

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

## 1. My Requirements

1. The *Decorator Class* should use `functools.wraps` so it has proper introspection and organization for later.
2. Access to the decorated instance should be possible.

   - In the example below, I do it by passing a `wrapped_self` argument to the `__call__` method.
3. As the title states, the *Decorator Class* must have parameters that you can tune for for each method.

## 2. An Example of What It Would Look Like

The ideal situation should look something like this:

```py
class A():

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    @LoggerDecorator(logger_name='test.log')
    def do_something(self):
        ...
```

with the *Decorator Class* being, so far (basic logger decorator based on a recipe coming from [David Beazley's Python Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449340377)):

```py
class LoggerDecorator():

    def __init__(self, func, logger_name):
        wraps(func)(self)
        self.logger_name = logger_name

    def config_logger(self):
        ... # for example, uses `self.logger_name` to configure the decorator

    def __call__(self, wrapped_self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.config_logger()
        wrapped_self.logger = self.logger
        func_to_return = self.__wrapped__(wrapped_self, *args, **kwargs)
        return func_to_return

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return types.MethodType(self, instance)
```

## 3. How Do I Fix It?

The error I'm getting refers to `__init__` not recognizing a third argument apparently:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

It has been suggested to me that I should be putting `func` in the `__call__` method. However, if I put it there as a parameter, `wrapped_self` isn't properly read as a parameter and I get this error:

```
__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'wrapped_self'
```

I've tried many things to fix this issue, including: putting `wraps(func)(self)` inside `__call__`; and many variations of [this very close but not quite filling all of the requirements solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5929178/4756173) (the problem with it is that I can't seem to be able to access `wrapped_self` anymore).

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  When I run your code I get `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`, which is the error I would expect.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I'm using `Python 3.7.2`. I'm gonna double check it as soon as I get home (about 20 minutes).

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, you are correct. That error should have been `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`. I'm gonna fix this in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're implementing a decorator that takes parameters, the `__init__` method of `LoggerDecorator` should take only the parameters that configures the decorator, while the `__call__` method instead should become the actual decorator that returns a wrapper function:

```
class LoggerDecorator():
    def __init__(self, logger_name):
        self.logger_name = logger_name
        self.config_logger()

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(wrapped_self, *args, **kwargs):
            wrapped_self.logger = self.logger
            func_to_return = func(wrapped_self, *args, **kwargs)
            return func_to_return
        return wrapper
```

Comment: So it is not possible to do it with the, in my opinion more elegant, `wraps(func)(self)` + `self.__wrapped__()` combo?

Comment: It is not possible because that only works for a decorator that takes no parameter, where the class when used as a callable is a decorator itself. To make a decorator take parameters, you have to make the class a configurator to the decorator, instead of making the class itself a decorator, so the `@wraps` decorator should be applied to the actual wrapper function within the `__call__` method, which itself becomes the true decorator that takes configuration from attributes initialized by the `__init__` method.

Comment: Dang it, @blhsing, you attack again! Thank you very much for the answer! One last thing though: would you say it's better that I keep or ditch the `__get__` method as it is programmed in the question?

Comment: I'm gonna grant you the official answer status, but I think it would be cool to add your comments about it not being possible to use the previously mentioned combo and the `__get__` method. Also, as a I can see that you know a lot about decorators, do you have any suggestions of books on the topic?

Comment: This was put into the edit suggestion, but, in case it is not accepted: The `__get__` method was fixing the fact that the `self` from the decorator class was getting mixed up with `self` from the decorated method. That happens because in the original question, the decorator itself was a class, but now the decorator is a returned function inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import wraps


class LoggerDecorator:

    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        print func, args, kwargs
        # do processing
        return func

@LoggerDecorator('lala')
def a():
    print 1
```

The above should work as expected. If you're planning to call the decorator using keyword arguments you can remove the `logger` from `__init__` and use `**kwargs` which will return a dict of the passed keywork arguments.

Comment: You mean I didn't decare a *default value* to the parameter after `func`? Because I tried what you posted before (and now), still not quite working...