# How to register python3 instance methods via a code for lookup?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm interpreting commands from a wire protocol. I have a class that encapsulates the command structure with something basic like

```
class Command:
    def __init__(self, commandType, body):
        self.commandType = commandType
        self.body = body

    @classmethod
    def decode(cls, someBytes):
        return cls(commandType=someBytes[0], body=someBytes[1:])

    def dispatch(self):
        pass # but could magic happen here?

    def command1(self):
        print("command1 stuff goes down")

    def command42(self):
        print("command42 stuff goes down")
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to somehow link the different `commandN` methods with the `commandType` so they could run in the `dispatch` method. A very naive/inefficient of `dispatch` could look like:

```
    def dispatch(self):
        methodName = f'command{self.commandType}'
        method = getattr(self, methodName, None)
        if method is not None:
            method(self)
```

But that only works as long as I name methods commandN. It would be nicer to use names that are monikers of what that command represents. That led me down the path of decorators. But a regular decorator wouldn't be enough, I would need a parameterized one. But after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters#5929165), I wasn't sure I wanted that. And some of the comments seemed to indicate it might be troublesome around instance methods.

Is there a different pattern that I'm missing that I can use to accomplish the association of instance methods with the different byte values?

Comment: I'm not sure how decorators would be useful here. In any case, the *idiomatic* way to *map* objects to other objects is to use a `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a simple translating dictionary be enough for you? Modify your `Command` class to include a translation dictionary as a class attribute that has the commandTypes as keys, and the method names as values. Then, inside your `dispatch` method, get the actual name of the command from the translation dictionary and run that.

```py
class Command:
    commandNames = {1: "print_command_type", 
                    2: "print_body"}

    def __init__(self, commandType, body):
        self.commandType = commandType
        self.body = body

    @classmethod
    def decode(cls, someBytes):
        return cls(commandType=someBytes[0], body=someBytes[1:])

    def dispatch(self):
        methodName = self.commandNames[self.commandType]
        method = getattr(self, methodName, None)
        if method is not None:
            method() # No need to pass `self`. It already is `self.method`

    def print_command_type(self):
        print(f"Command Type: {self.commandType}")

    def print_body(self):
        print(f"Body: {self.body}")

a = Command(1, 0)
b = Command(2, 0)
a.dispatch()
b.dispatch()
```

For more features, you can modify `dispatch` to accept `*args` and `**kwargs` to pass to your method, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post what I ended up doing (for now, until someone tells me a slicker way of doing this). Because it's a wire protocol, it's common to find these command codes in the form of an enum. And I wanted to leverage that so it showed up throughout the code. The enum is a sort of registering thing, if I have to add a new element (because of protocol revisions), I don't want to have to update the table initialization code like some header file. So I came up with the following that takes the (currently) accepted answer to just use a dict() and ran with it.

```
from enum import IntEnum, unique

@unique
class CommandCode(IntEnum):
    yes = 1
    no = 2
    maybe = 3

class Command(object):
    MethodTable = {}
    def __init__(self, code, message):
        super().__init__()
        self.code = code
        self.message = message

    def dispatch(self):
        # no "unknown code" protection here, left for student
        self.MethodTable[self.code](self)

    def yes(self):
        print("yes", self.message)

    def no(self):
        print("no", self.message)

    def maybe(self):
        print("maybe", self.message)

# registration phase that binds the enum to the class's MethodTable
for code in CommandCode:
    Command.MethodTable[code.value] = getattr(CommandCode, code.name)  


Command(code=1, message="bob").dispatch()
Command(code=2, message="fred").dispatch()
Command(code=3, message="george").dispatch()
Command(code=1, message="BOBBY").dispatch()
```

Update: I had to fix the first revision which was storing BoundMethods in the MethodTable rather than unbound methods.

Update 2: Realized I didn't need to be so clever with a dynamically growing MethodTable (too much time working with JIT languages I guess)