# self lost when using partial inside a decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'm trying to code a method from a class that uses a decorator from another class. The problem is that I need information stored in the Class that contains the decorator (ClassWithDecorator.decorator_param). To achieve that I'm using partial, injecting self as the first argument, but when I do that the self, from the class that uses the decorator " gets lost" somehow and I end up getting an error. Note that this does not happen if I remove `partial()` from `my_decorator()` and "self" will be correctly stored inside `*args`.

See the code sample:

```
from functools import partial


class ClassWithDecorator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.decorator_param = "PARAM"

    def my_decorator(self, decorated_func):
        def my_callable(ClassWithDecorator_instance, *args, **kwargs):
            # Do something with decorator_param
            print(ClassWithDecorator_instance.decorator_param)
            return decorated_func(*args, **kwargs)

        return partial(my_callable, self)


decorator_instance = ClassWithDecorator()


class WillCallDecorator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.other_param = "WillCallDecorator variable"

    @decorator_instance.my_decorator
    def decorated_method(self):
        pass


WillCallDecorator().decorated_method()
```

I get

```
PARAM
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "****/decorator.py", line 32, in <module>
    WillCallDecorator().decorated_method()
  File "****/decorator.py", line 12, in my_callable
    return decorated_func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: decorated_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

How can I pass the self corresponding to `WillCallDecorator()` into `decorated_method()` but at the same time pass information from its own class to `my_callable()` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decorators with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters)

Comment: But why `partial()` is removing self from the arguments?

Comment: The decorator works always on the unbound method which needs to receive the self explicitly as parameter yet.

Comment: Why are you using `partial` at all? The decorator can access `self` directly as a scoped variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So much simpler just to use the `self` variable you already have. There is absolutely no reason to be using `partial` or `partialmethod` here at all:

```
from functools import partial


class ClassWithDecorator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.decorator_param = "PARAM"

    def my_decorator(self, decorated_func):
        def my_callable(*args, **kwargs):
            # Do something with decorator_param
            print(self.decorator_param)
            return decorated_func(*args, **kwargs)

        return my_callable


decorator_instance = ClassWithDecorator()


class WillCallDecorator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.other_param = "WillCallDecorator variable"

    @decorator_instance.my_decorator
    def decorated_method(self):
        pass


WillCallDecorator().decorated_method()
```

Also, to answer your question about why your code didn't work, when you access `something.decorated_method()` the code checks whether `decorated_method` is a function and if so turns it internally into a call `WillCallDecorator.decorated_method(something)`. But the value returned from `partial` is a `functools.partial` object, not a `function`. So the class lookup binding won't happen here.

In more detail, `something.method(arg)` is equivalent to `SomethingClass.method.__get__(something, arg)` when `something` doesn't have an attribute `method` and its type `SomethingClass` does have the attribute and the attribute has a method `__get__` but the full set of steps for attribute lookup is quite complicated.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you may want to use [`partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod) instead of `partial`:

From the docs:

> `class functools.partialmethod(func, /, *args, **keywords)`
>
> When func is a non-descriptor callable, an appropriate bound method is created dynamically. This behaves like a normal Python function when used as a method: **the self argument will be inserted as the first positional argument**, even before the args and keywords supplied to the partialmethod constructor.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted, thanks. next time I will read the full official docs