# How to pass argument to a python decorator

Tags: python

I am going to write a function decorator that takes an argument and returns a decorator that can be used to control the type of the argument to a one-argument function. I expect a raising error happens in case the passed argument be in a wrong type.

```
def typecontrol(num_type): 
    def wrapper_function(num):
        if isinstance(num, num_type):
            return num
        else:
            raise TypeError

    return wrapper_function

@typecontrol(float)
def myfunc(num):
    print(num)
```

I expect for example, `myfunc(9.123)` should print 9.123 and `myfunc(9)` should raise an error. But it always raises type error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decorators with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters)

Comment: `def myfunc(num: float): ...` and using something like `mypy` to check your code would be a lot simpler and efficient.

Comment: So, you are trying to implement static typing into a duck typing language?

Comment: @KlausD. It's not really static typing. The type passed to `typecontrol` might not be known at compile time, so it's really a form of restricted dynamic typing. That said, *actual* static typing via `mypy` is probably sufficient for the OP.

Comment: @chepner I'm a Python developer, I have no idea what "compile time" is. ;) And BTW `mypy` is a tool from someone who misunderstood type annontations for people who misunderstood type annotations.

Comment: @KlausD. Type annotations are what they are. I don't think anyone has ever claimed that `mypy` makes Python a statically typed language, rather than a tool that provides some of the benefits of static typing in a language that is, and will remain, dynamically typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typecontrol` will be a function that *returns* the decorator, not the decorator itself. You need an extra nested function:

```
def typecontrol(num_type):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper_function(num):
            if isinstance(num, num_type):
                f(num)
            else:
                raise TypeError
        return wrapper_function
    return decorator

@typecontrol(float)
def myfunc(num):
    print(num)
```

The wrapper function will take care of *calling* the wrapped function if the typecheck passes, rather than returning the typechecked argument.

In your code as written, `num` is actually the function you are decorating, so you are checking if a function is an instance of (in this case), `float`.

Some examples:

```
>>> myfunc(3.0)
3.0
>>> myfunc("foo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tmp.py", line 7, in wrapper_function
    raise TypeError
TypeError
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, a good explanation on writing decorators with arguments is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters).

However, it seems like you want to enforce types (I've gone down a similar rabbit hole before in Python) so depending on your use case would I possibly recommend two options:

1. If you want to make sure that your program is typed correctly **prior to runtime**, use the [`mypy` static type checker](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
2. If you need to parse/validate input values **at runtime**, I would highly suggest the `pydantic` package. It allows you to create "struct-like" objects (similar to a `NamedTuple`, or a `dataclass`) that will enforce runtime type checks and will appropriately coerce the input at runtime using Python 3.6+ type hints. Documentation and some helpful examples can be found [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io).

Depending on your use case, I hope either of these two help!