# How to properly use a decorator? (TypeError: wrapper() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given)

Tags: python, module, package, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to write a decorator that checks if specific packages are available before using a function.

In the example below, `numpy` should not throw an error but `non_existent_test_package` should inform the user that they need to install packages to use this functionality.  The point of this is to reduce dependencies.

#### UPDATE based on @henry-harutyunyan suggestion

---

```
import numpy as np
import importlib

def check_available_packages(packages):
    if isinstance(packages,str):
        packages = [packages]
    packages = np.asarray(sorted(set(packages)))
    def wrapper(func):
        installed = list()
        for package in packages:
            try: 
                globals()[package] = importlib.import_module(package)
                installed.append(True)
            except ImportError:
                installed.append(False)
        installed = np.asarray(installed)
        assert np.all(installed), "Please install the following packages to use this functionality:\n{}".format(", ".join(map(lambda x: "'{}'".format(x), packages[~installed])))
        return func
    return wrapper

@check_available_packages(["numpy"])
def f():
    print("This worked")

@check_available_packages(["numpy", "non_existent_test_package"])
def f():
    print("This shouldn't work")

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-222-5e8224fb30bd> in <module>
#      23     print("This worked")
#      24 
# ---> 25 @check_available_packages(["numpy", "non_existent_test_package"])
#      26 def f():
#      27     print("This shouldn't work")

# <ipython-input-222-5e8224fb30bd> in wrapper(func)
#      15                 installed.append(False)
#      16         installed = np.asarray(installed)
# ---> 17         assert np.all(installed), "Please install the following packages to use this functionality:\n{}".format(", ".join(map(lambda x: "'{}'".format(x), packages[~installed])))
#      18         return func
#      19     return wrapper

# AssertionError: Please install the following packages to use this functionality:
# 'non_existent_test_package'
```

Now the decorator seems to be checking the packages exist at run time instead of when the function is actually called.  How can I adjust this code?

Comment: `check_available_packages` is a decorator *factory*, it returns a decorator which must take a single argument - the function to decorate. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5929107/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```py
import numpy as np
import importlib


def check_available_packages(packages):
    if isinstance(packages, str):
        packages = [packages]
    packages = np.asarray(sorted(set(packages)))

    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper():
            installed = list()
            for package in packages:
                try:
                    globals()[package] = importlib.import_module(package)
                    installed.append(True)
                except ImportError:
                    installed.append(False)
            installed = np.asarray(installed)
            assert np.all(installed), "Please install the following packages to use this functionality:\n{}".format(
                ", ".join(packages[~installed]))
            func()

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@check_available_packages(["numpy"])
def foo():
    print("This worked")


@check_available_packages(["numpy", "non_existent_test_package"])
def bar():
    print("This shouldn't work")


foo()
bar()
```

The issue is that the `wrapper()` function you have is taking an argument, while by definition it doesn't need any. So passing `_` in this statement `wrapper(_)` will do the job.

`_` is dummy, it can't be used, but it still is something. The IDEs won't complain about the unused variable either.

To execute the decorator only when the function is called you need to use the decorator factory as above. See [this reference](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845#decorator-functions-with-decorator-arguments) for more details.

Comment: Thank you.  So this is kind of working.  I don't want `check_available_packages` to evaluate unless `f()` is called.  Right now it looks like it's checking for the packages at runtime instead of when the function is called.  How can I adapt to have this functionality?

Comment: @O.rka Ohh I see, pls add it to the question and let me see what we can do.

Comment: @O.rka modified to be executed only when the function is called.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the check to happen when the underlying function is called, you need an extra level of wrapping around it:

```
import functools

def check_available_packages(packages):
    if isinstance(packages,str):
        packages = [packages]
    packages = sorted(set(packages))
    def decorator(func):                # we need an extra layer of wrapping
        @functools.wraps(func)          # the wrapper replaces func in the global namespace
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):   # so it needs to accept any arguments that func does
            missing_packages = []       # no need for fancy numpy array indexing, a list will do
            for package in packages:
                try: 
                    globals()[package] = importlib.import_module(package)
                except ImportError:
                    missing_packages.append(package)
            assert not missing_packages, "Please install the following packages to use this functionality:\n{}".format(", ".join(missing_packages))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)  # call the function after doing the library checking!
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

I removed the reliance on `numpy` from the code, it seemed completely unnecessary to me, and especially if you're testing if `numpy` is installed, it doesn't make sense to require it for the checks to work.

Comment: Thank you!  This is much cleaner than I had before.  Also, thanks for explaining what is happening.  I will need to look into functools.wraps a bit more.  So what was happening when I did not have the extra layer `decorator` function and only the `wrapper`?

Comment: You don't *need* `functools.wraps`, it's just nice to have when you're not returning the wrapper in place of the original function. It replaces the `wrapper` function's `__name__` and `__doc__` attributes (and maybe a few other things, I forget all the details) with the one from `func`, so it makes it easier to figure out what the function does later on. The decorated function works just fine without it. Anyway, without the extra layer, you *had* to do the library check when the decorator was applied, because you don't get to intercept calls to the function later on.