# How to add wait/sleep decorator to steps functions (Behave)?

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-behave

Using Python/Selenium/Behave:

I'm wondering how to correctly add wait/sleep decorators to steps functions?

I have setup a helper.py with my decorator function:

```
import time

def wait(secs):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
            time.sleep(secs)
            return ret
        return wrapper
    return decorator

class Helper(object):
    pass
```

In my steps file, I'm calling the wait decorator after the behave decorator to match the step:

```
from behave import step
from features.helper import wait

@step('I observe a login error')
@wait(3)
def step_impl(context):
    #time.sleep(3)
    assert context.login_page.check_login_error() is not None
```

But when I execute the step from my feature file, there is no wait/sleep being executed, and the assert fails.  How can I execute the wait decorator in this case?

Comment: You cannot add parameters to decorators like that, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters

Comment: You're calling your decorated function, _before_ waiting the 3 seconds. Then you're waiting 3 seconds after the decorated function is finished. Is that really the behavior you wanted? If not, try to just move the `time.sleep` call to before the function-call.

Comment: Personally, I think using that wait decorator is obscuring your tests. I would include a `Then I wait for 3 seconds` step to be more explicit. Even better, if you are using Selenium I would use an explicit wait to find the error element when it shows up, rather than hardcoding a sleep into your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the problem is due to call the target function before `sleep`. So you can just swap `func` and `time.sleep` calling:

```
def wait(secs):
     def decorator(func):
         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
             time.sleep(secs)
             return func(*args, **kwargs)
         return wrapper
     return decorator
```