# Write a decorator with parameter in Python

Tags: python, decorator

Suppose a decorator changes the behavior of a function `to_lower()`:

```
def transition(fn):
    def to_upper(text: str):
        print('the original behavior:' + fn(text))
        return text.upper()
    
    def to_capital(text: str):
        print('the original behavior:' + fn(text))
        return text.capitalize()

    return to_upper

@transition
def to_lower(text: str):
    return text.lower()

print(to_lower('AaBb'))
>>>
the original behavior:aabb
AABB
```

This works fine, and if we change the return statement of `transition` from `return to_upper` to `return to_capital`, it changes the behavior from `to_lower` to `to_capital`, which makes `AaBb` to `Aabb`

Instead of manually modifying the `return` of the decorator,
can we modify the decorator with sort of parameter like `mode`, if we call
`@transition(mode='to_upper')`, it works as `return to_upper` and when we call
`@transition(mode='to_capital')`, it works as `return to_capital` for the decorator?

Comment: This answer is very comprehensive and might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5929165/7013263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very basic implementation:

```py
def transition(mode):
    def deco(f):
        if mode == "to_upper":
            def wrapper(text):
                return text.upper()
        elif mode == "to_capital":
            def wrapper(text):
                return text.capitalize()
        else:
            # implement different behavior for other use cases  
            pass
        return wrapper
    return deco

    
    
        
    
@transition(mode="to_capital")
def to_lower(text):
    return text.lower()


@transition(mode="to_upper")
def to_lower(text):
    return text.lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an additional layer for the decorator argument. Example:

```
import functools

def transition(mode):
    def wrapped(fn):
        @functools.wraps(fn)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            res = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            if mode == 'to_capital':
                return res.capitalize()
            elif mode == 'to_upper':
                return res.upper()
            else:
                raise ValueError("invalid mode")

        return inner

    return wrapped
```

which can be applied as

```
@transition(mode='to_capital')
def to_lower(text: str):
    return text.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make parameters optional and also code is cleaner.

```
from functools import wraps

def process(fn, mode):
    @wraps(fn)
    def newfn(text):
        if mode == "to_upper":
            return text.upper()
        else:
            return text.capitalize()
    return newfn

def transition(fn=None, /, *, mode="to_upper"):
    def wrap(fn):
        return process(fn, mode)
    if fn is None:
        return wrap
    return wrap(fn)

@transition(mode="upper")
def to_lower(text: str):
    return text.lower()

@transition(mode="capitalize")
def to_lower(text: str):
    return text.lower()

@transition
def to_lower(text: str):
    return text.lower()
```