# is *args the proper way to pass parameters to/from decorated functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, decorator, python-decorators

I have the following (simple, home-grade) problem: I keep the state of a program in a JSON file and have several functions that make use of that "database". Some just need to load the DB, some need to load it, and then write back to file.

I wanted to use decorators on these functions to centralize the reading and writing of the database. Below is a simplified version of my code, with two functions: one that only consumes the DB, and another one that also modifies it. This code works and returns the expected values<sup>(*)</sup>

Please note how the database (`db`) is passed between the decorators and the function

```
def load_db(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("loading DB")
        db = 5
        # the db was loaded and is now passed to the function actually making use of it
        func(db)
    return wrapper

def load_and_write_db(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("loading DB")
        db = 5
        # the db was loaded and is now passed to the function actually making use of it
        # we will get back the changed database
        db = func(db)
        # now we write the DB to the disk
        print(f"writing DB: {db}")
    return wrapper

@load_db
def do_stuff_load_only(*db):
    # a function that just consumes the DB, without changing it
    print(f"initial DB is {db}")

@load_and_write_db
def do_stuff_load_and_write(*db):
    # a function that consumes and chnages the DB (which then needs to be updated on disk)
    print(f"initial DB is {db}")
    db = 10
    print(f"changed DB to {db}")
    # returning the new DB
    return db


do_stuff_load_only()
do_stuff_load_and_write()

# Output:
# 
# loading DB
# initial DB is (5,)
# loading DB
# initial DB is (5,)
# changed DB to 10
# writing DB: 10
```

Is this the proper approach to pass information between the decorators and the function? Specifically, **should I rely on `*db` to indicate only the decorator passes an argument to the function, and nothing is passed when it is actually called from the code** (last two lines)?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25827070/903011) explains very nicely how arguments should be passed, it just fails short to address my question about decorated functions sometomes receiving an argument, and sometimes not.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> *Almost*. `db` passed to the function arrives as a tuple, something I can live with

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. The title asks about using ``*`` to pass things *to the decorator*, the code shows using ``*`` to pass things *to the decorated function* . Note that ``*`` is not directly tied to decorators, it indicates variadic arguments – decorators often are variadic in their arguments, but do not have to be.

Comment: Why does `load_db` define a wrapper that ignores the argument passed to the decorated function and replace it with a hard-coded value instead?

Comment: What do you mean by *"my question about decorated functions sometimes receiving an argument, and sometimes not"*? It seems to me that your decorated function **always** receives the `db` argument, because the decorator always passes it. If you want a single parameter that may or may not be passed as an argument, it would be more sensible to give it a default value (i.e. `def foo(db=None): ...`) rather than use the `*args` syntax which allows an arbitrary number of arguments (not just 0 or 1).

Comment: @kaya3: * It seems to me that your decorated function always receives the db argument,* - please look at the last two lines of my code, nothing is passed. Now, the named parameters is indeed a much better idea, did not think about that, thanks!

Comment: @chepner: this is to simulate the load of the data from disk, and assigning it to `db` (and then passing for the actual use)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: yes you are right, I mistyped what I meant, I will correct that right away.

Comment: @WoJ I looked at your code already; please read my comment more carefully. Just because you call the (decorated) function without passing an argument, doesn't mean the function doesn't *receive* the argument; the decorator passes it. The decorator **always** passes it, so the function always receives it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your decorator is written, `do_stuff_load_only` can be defined with a regular parameter, even if you won't actually pass an argument when you call it. That's because the name `do_stuff_load_only` isn't going to be bound to a one-argument function; it's going to be bound to the *zero*-argument function `wrapper` defined inside `load_db`. `wrapper` itself will take care of passing an argument to the actual one-argument function being decorated.

```
@load_db
def do_stuff_load_only(db):
    # a function that just consumes the DB, without changing it
    print(f"initial DB is {db}")


do_stuff_load_only()
```

Defining `do_stuff_load_only(*db)` would *work*, but changes what is actually bound to `db`; in this case, it would be the singleton tuple `(5,)` rather than the integer `5`.

If you think this looks awkward, that's because it is. `load_db` has a "hidden" side effect that you shouldn't have to worry about. A context manager would probably be more fitting here:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def load_db():
    print("Initializing the database")
    yield 5  # provide it
    print("Tearing down the database")


def do_stuff_load_only(*db):
    # a function that just consumes the DB, without changing it
    print(f"initial DB is {db}")


with load_db() as db:
    do_stuff_load_only(db)
```

Now the definition and use of the function bound to `do_stuff_load_only` agree, with the details of how the database is created and destroyed hidden by the context manager. The output of the above code is

```
Initializing the database
initial DB is 5
Tearing down the database
```

Comment: Thank you for the context manager information - this looks very promising. As a side note, shouldn't the decorator be `@contextmanager`? Wile for the "readonly" version the context manager is straightforward, is it possible to use it in the "read, then write" one?

Comment: To answer my own question: probably yes, I am checking with class-based context managers that handle `__enter__` and `__exit__`

Comment: I would try to use `contextmanager` first, as it's less verbose. Basically, anything before the `yield` is what goes into the resulting `__enter__` method; the thing yielded is what gets returned by `__enter__`, and everything after the `yield` is the `__exit__` method. `contextmanager` just generates the methods for you.

Comment: (Unless, of course, you already have an existing class to which it makes sense to add `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.)

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear - I already wrote the class but I will refactor it to use `contextmanager`