# How to remove the self argument from a decorator's arguments if there is one

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, decorator, self

Suppose I have a simple decorator, and a classes method and a function which I both decorate with that decorator:

```py
import functools

def decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def call(*args):
        print(args)
        func(*args)
    return call

class cls:
    @decorator
    def meth(self, a):
        pass

@decorator
def func(c):
    pass

cls().meth("a")
func("c")
```

I get following output:

```py
(<__main__.cls object at 0x7f4665c50130>, 'a')
('c',)
```

But I want to remove the `self` argument when the decorator is used on a method, so that the output becomes:

```py
('a',)
('c',)
```

But, if I simply add `args.pop(0)`, I will remove the first argument even if it is not `self`. How can I only remove the first argument if it is `self` ?

**Note**: I read some solutions with a long code using `inspect` - but there must be a shorter, easier way in this great and simple-to-use programming language ?

**EDIT**: Using `@staticmethod` is not an option for me, because I need the `self` parameter in the method itself. I only don't want it to get *printed*.

Comment: What about `@staticmethod` decorator ?

Comment: @May.D no, this is not an option for me; plus I don't see the benefit of it - I edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to explicitly tell your decorator that it's decorating a class method. Your decorator will take a keyword argument denoting that.

```
def decorator(is_classmethod=False):
    def wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def call(*args):
            if is_classmethod:
                print(args[1:])  # omit args[0]
            else:
                print(args)
            return func(*args)      # pass all the args to the function
        return call
    return wrapper

class cls:
    @decorator(is_classmethod=True)
    def meth(self, a):
        pass

@decorator
def func(c):
    pass

cls().meth("a")
func("c")
```

Since the user already knows what they're decorating, you can avoid complicated introspection code in the decorator, and give the user flexibility of processing the first argument or not.

please take a look at my answer to this SO question: [Decorators with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters/25827070#25827070) for a cleaner (IMHO) way to write decorators with parameters. There are some really good answers in that post.

Comment: Hmm … If I don't get another solution that auto-detects that, I'll accept this answer tomorrow ! +1

Comment: `func("c")` print nothing

Comment: You forgot to use `is_classmethod` to alter the behavior of `call`.

Comment: You could also replace `is_classmethod` with an integer parameter that gets used as the starting value of the slice directly.

Comment: updated the code example with the branch logic. @chepner, thanks for the review.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `args` for output by existence of some python magic. For example:

```
import functools

def decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def call(*args):
        print(list(filter(lambda x: not hasattr(x, '__dict__'), args)))
        func(*args)
    return call

class cls:
    @decorator
    def meth(self, a):
        pass

@decorator
def func(c):
    pass

cls().meth("a")  # ['a']
func("c")  # ['c']
```

Comment: This will not work if you pass any mutable class as the method arguments.
`def meth(self, other_class_instance)` will get caught in the filter.

Comment: Write please a simple example of such thing. I think that we can find solution)

Comment: As I understand author need to see inputed variables and no other classes information.

Comment: OP wants to avoid printing the `self` reference (which is the first argument for the function call if the function is a class or an instance method), and print all other arguments. if any of the arguments turns out to be an object  implementing the `__dict__` attribute, it will get filtered by your decorator

Comment: If I put `print(hasattr(self, '__dict__'))` in `cls.meth`, I get `True`. How does `filter(lambda x: not hasattr(x, '__dict__'), args)` work, then ? Please explain.