# How to cache result of function depending on the value returned

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, lru

I am aware of [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) and [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) (since Python 3.9) but I struggle with caching these arguments of a function which do not return `None` (or any other specific value):

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def my_fun(link):
    res = fetch_data(link)
    return res
```

`res` is None when `fetch_data` is encountering an intermittent error. And this is when I do not want the result to be cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cache for functions with positional arguments

I figured that I can implement the cache on my own using a dictionary and store the result only when the return value is not `None`:

```
from functools import wraps

def my_cache(no_cache_result=tuple()):
    if no_cache_result is None:
        no_cache_result = tuple()

    cache = dict()

    def decorator(fun):
        @wraps(fun)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            assert len(kwargs) == 0
            if args in cache:
                print('cache: taken from cache')
                return cache[args]
            else:
                res = fun(*args, **kwargs)
                if res not in no_cache_result:
                    print('cache: stored in cache')
                    cache[args] = res
                else:
                    print('cache: NOT stored')
                return res

        return wrapper
    return decorator


@my_cache(no_cache_result=[None])
def my_fun(a):
    print(f'my_fun: called with {a}')
    if a <= 1:
        return a
    else:
        return None


my_fun(0)
my_fun(1)
my_fun(2)

my_fun(0)
my_fun(1)
my_fun(2)
```

Which prints (as expected):

```
my_fun: called with 0
cache: stored in cache
my_fun: called with 1
cache: stored in cache
my_fun: called with 2
cache: NOT stored
cache: taken from cache
cache: taken from cache
my_fun: called with 2
cache: NOT stored
```

### Cache for functions with positional and *keyword* arguments

The solution above limits the functions that can be decorated to those with only positional arguments and not keyword arguments.

At the expense of small slow-down it can be improved in the following way:

```
def my_cache(no_cache_result=tuple()):
    if no_cache_result is None:
        no_cache_result = tuple()

    cache = dict()

    def decorator(fun):
        @wraps(fun)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            _kwargs = tuple(kwargs.items())
            if (args, _kwargs) in cache:
                print('cache: taken from cache')
                return cache[(args, _kwargs)]
            else:
                res = fun(*args, **kwargs)
                if res not in no_cache_result:
                    print('cache: stored in cache')
                    cache[(args, _kwargs)] = res
                else:
                    print('cache: NOT stored')
                return res

        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Which works as expected:

```
@my_cache(no_cache_result=[None, ])
def my_fun2(a, b=7):
    print(f'my_fun2: called with {a}, {b}')
    if a <= 1:
        return a
    else:
        return None


my_fun2(0, b=2)
my_fun2(1)
my_fun2(2)

my_fun2(0, b=2)
my_fun2(1)
my_fun2(2)
```

Printing:

```
my_fun2: called with 0, 2
cache: stored in cache
my_fun2: called with 1, 7
cache: stored in cache
my_fun2: called with 2, 7
cache: NOT stored
cache: taken from cache
cache: taken from cache
my_fun2: called with 2, 7
cache: NOT stored
```

### How it works?

##### Decorators

The details on the implementation of wrappers (also, with arguments) you can find amply discussed in answers to [Decorators with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters).

##### Forbidden return values - performance

The performance of the cache depends on the type of passed `no_cache_result` argument. In case you wish to restrict caching for more than a few return values, it is recommended to pass a set, instead of typically used list because `if x in no_cache_result` operation is much quicker for sets than for lists.