# Creating a decorator with parameter for a class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

Trying to create a decorator for a few methods in a class. The decorator works as expected without parameters:

```
class OtherMenu:                                                                                                        
    current_page = 'algo'                                                                                               
                          
                                                                                   
class MenuSidebarWebScreen(OtherMenu):                                                                                  
                                                                                                                     
    def decorator(foo):                                                                                                 
        def magic(self):                                                                                                
            import ipdb                                                                                                 
            ipdb.set_trace()                                                                                            
            print("start magic")                                                                                        
            foo(self)                                                                                                   
            print("end magic")                                                                                          
        return magic                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                     
    @decorator                                                                                                          
    def go_to_home_page(self):                                                                                          
        if self.current_page == "Home":                                                                                 
            print(f'Already in the {self.current_page}, skipping menu interaction.')                                    
            return                                                                                                      
        # Do awesome stuff over here
        self.current_page = "Home"
```

```
>>> from features.steps.web_ui.menu.menu_sidebar_web_screen import MenuSidebarWebScreen
>>> menu = MenuSidebarWebScreen()
>>> menu.go_to_home_page()
ipdb> foo
<function MenuSidebarWebScreen.go_to_home_page at 0x10dbd1280>
ipdb> self
<features.steps.web_ui.menu.menu_sidebar_web_screen.MenuSidebarWebScreen object at 0x10c85e280>
ipdb>
```

But when I add a parameter to the decorator, like this

```
        @decorator("Something")  <----------- Added a parameter to the decorator
        def go_to_home_page(self):                                                                                          
            if self.current_page == "Home":
```

the behavior changes. First of all, the decorator method is called as soon as I import the class (instead of calling the class method). Also the values from the pdb itself change to:

```
>>> from features.steps.web_ui.menu.menu_sidebar_web_screen import MenuSidebarWebScreen
ipdb> self
<function MenuSidebarWebScreen.go_to_home_page at 0x10a07c310>
ipdb> foo
'Something'
```

What is the proper way to use the class inside the decorator? I was hoping to use these parts of the code to the decorator itself:

```
            if self.current_page == "Home":                                                                                 
                print(f'Already in the {self.current_page}, skipping menu interaction.')                                    
                return                                                                                                      
            ... ------> Everything else, that will remain on the go_to_home_page method
            self.current_page = "Home"
```

Comment: Could you give a [mre] of what _doesn't_ work? Also _"the decorator method is called as soon as I import the class"_ is surely the expected behaviour in either case - a decorator is called with the function/method it's decorating.

Comment: Added more details with the Python interpreter. Could you have a look now please?

Comment: And do you actually change the decorator to account for the fact that you're now expecting it to be a decorator _factory_?

Comment: I suspect this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5929107/3001761