# Try each function of a class with functools.wraps decorator

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper, functools

I'm trying to define a **decorator** in order to execute a class method, **try it first** and, if an error is detected, raise it mentioning the method in which failed, so as to the user could see in which method is the error.

Here I show a **MRE** (Minimal, Reproducible Example) of my code.

```
from functools import wraps

def trier(func):
    """Decorator for trying A-class methods"""
    @wraps(func)
    def inner_func(self, name, *args):
        
        try:
            func(self, *args)
        
        except:
            print(f"An error apeared while {name}")
    
    return inner_func
    
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._animals = 2
        self._humans = 5
    
    @trier('getting animals')
    def animals(self, num):
        return self._animals + num
    
    @trier('getting humans')
    def humans(self):
        return self._humans

A().animals
```

Many **errors** are raising, like:

> TypeError: inner_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

or misunderstanding self class with self function.

Comment: You will need to look up how to make a decorator which takes a parameter. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to Stefan's answer, the following simply uses `@trier` without any parameters to decorate functions, and then when printing out the error message we can get the name with `func.__name__`.

```
from functools import wraps

def trier(func):
    """Decorator for trying A-class methods"""
    @wraps(func)
    def inner_func(self, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        except:
            print(f"An error apeared in {func.__name__}")

    return inner_func

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._animals = 2
        self._humans = 5

    @trier
    def animals(self, num):
        return self._animals + num

    @trier
    def humans(self):
        return self._humans

print(A().animals(1))
```

I also fixed a couple of bugs in the code: In `trier`'s try and except the result of calling `func` was never returned, and you need to include `**kwargs` in addition to `*args` so you can use named parameters. I.e. `A().animals(num=1)` only works when you handle `kwargs`.

Comment: Thank your very much for the aid. I think this is the answer that better solve my problem. `func.__doc__` is also completley useful if methods are well defined.

Answer (score 2):

For decorators with parameters, you need one more level of nesting:

```py
from functools import wraps


def trier(name):
    def wrapper(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                print(f"An error apeared while executing {name!r}")
        return inner
    return wrapper


class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self._animals = 2
        self._humans = 5

    @trier('getting animals')
    def animals(self, num):
        return self._animals + num

    @trier('getting humans')
    def humans(self):
        return self._hoomans # wrong attribute name


a = A()
a.humans() # An error apeared while executing 'getting humans'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally I've done it like @hostingutilities.com proposed. It has not been necesary that level of nesting, although your answer is completley useful

Answer (score 2):

I would do this like this, hope it helps.

```py
from functools import wraps
import sys


def trier(func):
    """Decorator for trying A-class methods"""
    @wraps(func)
    def inner_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'Calling {func.__name__}')
        try:
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        except:
            print(f"An error apeared on function : {func.__name__}")
            e = sys.exc_info()[2]
            raise Exception(f"Exception occured on line: {e.tb_next.tb_lineno}")

    return inner_func


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._animals = 2
        self._humans = 5

    @trier
    def get_animals(self, num):
        return self._animals + num

    @trier
    def get_humans(self):
        return self._humans

    @trier
    def function_raising_exception(self):
        raise Exception('This is some exception')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    a.get_animals(2)
    a.function_raising_exception()
```

Using `e = sys.exc_info()[2]`, you can get the traceback message as well and point to the line at which the exception is occurred.

It's worth noting that when a decorator is written, it should be applicable to other functions that you'd use in your app.