# Passing a global variable to a decorator in Python

Tags: python, decorator, apscheduler

I'm trying to use a decorator for a function, while trying to pass a global variable to the decorator. However, I get an error message at the line with the decorator (@) stating that `scheduler` is not defined...

```
def wrap_task(scheduler_in):
    def inner(task):
        try:
            task()
        except:
            logger_sub.exception("Error!!!!")
            scheduler_in.shutdown(wait=False)
    return inner

@wrap_task(scheduler_in = scheduler)
def print_job():
    print("pipeline")
    raise FileExistsError

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler() # from APScheduler
    scheduler.add_job(print_job,'date',id="print_job")
    scheduler.add_listener(my_listener,EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
    (...)
```

P.S.: The problem shouldn't be to use `scheduler` before it's defined, since I also create a listener for this scheduler and the listener itself uses the same shutdown command without any error.

Comment: You should define `scheduler` before `print_job`

Comment: well, you use a variable before you define it, that's the problem. you should also have a look at how to write paramterised decorators, your is... wrong. :)

Comment: Wrap the task when you add it instead of using a decorator? `scheduler.add_job(wrap_task(scheduler_in=scheduler)(print_job),'date',id="print_job")`

Comment: @DMalan If I do that, I get this message: «TypeError: func must be a callable or a textual reference to one»

Comment: @timgeb could please be more precise in how it's wrong? How would I correct it?

Comment: `wrap_task(scheduler_in = scheduler)` returns the function `inner`. `inner` is then applied to `print_job` like this: `print_job = inner(print_job)`. But now `print_job` isn't a function anymore, `inner` just executes `print_job` immediately and returns `None`. So now, `print_job = None` but you probably wanted a modified function `print_job`.

Comment: @timgeb I don't see how what I've done is wrong, given what I see in this link in Example #1. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-with-parameters-in-python/

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. This is the worst tutorial I have ever seen. example #1 is particularly bad. Try executing it. `my_func` runs immediately and after execution is set to `None`. print `my_func` and see for yourself. Their decorator made the function unusable.

Comment: @timgeb how would you suggest to solve the issue, then? By the way, if you know of a better tutorial, I would be much obliged.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. forget that article and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters) instead.