request data not able to access with this code in wrapper function how can i python3 django decorator
not able to access request data in deorator how can i do this ? in my wrapper function
def my_decorator(view_func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('-start-')
        print(request.data)
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        print('-now-')
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return response
    return wrapper



class HandymanCompleteProfileIos(APIView):
    @my_decorator
    def post(self, request, format = None):
        return JsonResponse({"A":"a"})


SO what's the output? What is being printed right now?

-start-
<apps.users.views.HandymanCompleteProfileIos object at 0x7f5fac4f15e0>
(<rest_framework.request.Request: POST '/api/complete-handyman-profile-ios'>,)
{}
-now--

if i print request.data then error come

Because request is not  request, it is self, as you can see by <apps.users.views.HandymanCompleteProfileIos object at 0x7f5fac4f15e0>

The first argument of an instance method is self, so the wrapper function should be defined with self as the first argument, and pass it to the wrapped method when calling it:
def my_decorator(view_func):
    def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('-start-')
        print(request.data)
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        print('-now-')
        response = view_func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        return response
    return wrapper

At the request of your comment, here is how you can parameterize the decorator with an additional argument extra_arg:
def my_decorator(extra_arg):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            print('-start-')
            print(request.data)
            print(args)
            print(kwargs)
            print(extra_arg)
            print('-now-')
            response = view_func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
            return response
        return wrapper
    return decorator


i want to add one more thing in this decorator one parameter when we call
@my_decorator('abc') now how can i print abc in this function

What's this one more thing?

i have added dear

Like a default argument value for the decorator?

yes one parmeter or more then 2

@JaskaranSingh Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/decorators-with-parameters for ways to parameterize your decorator.

could you please eidt this function

@JaskaranSingh I've updated the answer accordingly then.

try this:
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView

def my_decorator(view_func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('-start-')
        # Accessing request data
        print(request.data)  # For DRF, use request.data
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        print('-now-')
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return response
    return wrapper

class HandymanCompleteProfileIos(APIView):
    @my_decorator
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        return JsonResponse({"A": "a"})


Is this ChatGPT? You didn't change anything in the original code, just added the imports, comments and spaces.
